# Automatic redirect after login with react-router

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router

I wanted to build a Facebook login into my **react/react-router/flux** application.
I have a listener registered on the login event and would like to redirect the user to `'/dashboard'` if they are logged in. How can I do that? `location.push` didn't work very well, except after reloading the page completely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react router - Redirection after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119793/react-router-redirection-after-login)

Comment: @PaulRoub This question was asked several *months* before the question you linked to. I don't think its a duplicate

Comment: simplest way https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916596/3966458

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **React Router v0.13**

The `Router` instance [returned from `Router.create`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/create.md) can be passed around (or, if inside a React component, you can get it from [the context object](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/RouterContext.md)), and contains methods [like `transitionTo`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/RouterContext.md#transitiontoroutenameorpath-params-query) that you can use to transition to a new route.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! Do you know an example how I would pass a route?

Comment: @DanielSchmidt Did you take a look at the `transitionTo` documentation? It shows several examples. You'd probably do `router.transitionTo('/dashboard')`

Comment: There is an issue with react.router discussing about this.

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/975

This is solved by updating React to 0.13.1 and React Router to 0.13.2

Comment: the links are broken because the api documentation was removed, for reference we can be found in https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/051fd039a9880e0356a79e9522f62549f1ef653a/docs/api

Comment: Thanks for this answer, where in the component lifecycle should we trigger a redirect using this method?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to update the broken links on this - but this doesn't really apply to React Router v4 and I'm not exactly sure the best way to re-write it

Answer (score 33):

> **React Router v3**

This is what I do

```
var Router = require('react-router');
Router.browserHistory.push('/somepath');
```

> **React Router v4**

Now we can use the `<Redirect>`component in React Router v4.

Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
export default class LoginComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        if(this.state.isLoggedIn === true){
            return (<Redirect to="/your/redirect/page" />);
        }else{
            return (<div>Login Please</div>);
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: Noob one maybe, but I'm wondering why `import Router from 'react-router'` does not work as  `var Router = require('react-router');`does.

Comment: @Ben You need to use `import {Router} from 'react-router'`

Comment: @Ben but in this case you need to use as `import {browserHistory} from 'react-router'`

Comment: import is from ES2015 dialect.

Comment: What if you're using hash history?

Comment: @Philll_t use `withRouter` decorator for components.

Answer (score 11):

> **React Router v2**

Even though the question is already answered, I think it's relevant to post the solution that worked for me, since it wasn't covered in any of the solutions given here.

First, I'm using the router context on my `LoginForm` component

```
LoginForm.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

After that, I can access the `router` object inside my `LoginForm` component

```
handleLogin() {
  this.context.router.push('/anotherroute');
}
```

PS: working on React-router version 2.6.0

Comment: Where in the code do you add `LoginForm.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};`

Comment: `If you insist on using context despite these warnings, try to isolate your use of context to a small area and avoid using the context API directly when possible so that it's easier to upgrade when the API changes.` from react doc so is it good to use Context?

Answer (score 3):

> **React Router v3**

### Navigating Outside of Components

create your app with Router like this

```
// Your main file that renders a <Router>:
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import routes from './app/routes'

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />,
  mountNode
)
```

Somewhere like a Redux middleware or Flux action:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

// Go to /some/path.
browserHistory.push('/some/path')

// Go back to previous location.
browserHistory.goBack()
```

[react-router/tree/v3/docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

Answer (score 3):

> **React Router v4.2.0**

I am using **React-16.2.0** & **React-router-4.2.0**

And I get solution by this code
 `this.props.history.push("/");`

**My working code:**

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    if(data.status == 200){
        this.props.history.push("/");
        console.log('Successfully Login');
  }
})
```

I was following this document [redirect-on-login-and-logout](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/redirect-on-login-and-logout.html)

I was also try by `return <Redirect to='/'  />` But unlucky, this not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

**React router v5 using hooks**

**These steps are for authorisation redirect. But can be used for login/logout redirection also.**

The `<Redirect/>` accepts `to` prop as a string or an object. We can utilise the object to pass the redirection path after login/logout using hooks easily.

1. Get the pathname of url from where the `<Redirect/>` is called using
   `useLocation()`
   `const {pathname} = useLocation()`
2. In the `to` prop of `<Redirect/>` pass in the following object:
   `<Redirect to={{pathname:'/login',state: {referrer: pathname}}/>`
3. In the Login component access the route state variable using `useLocation()` hook and use the `useHistory()` hook to redirect after successful login.
   `const history = useHistory();`
   `const location = useLocation();`
   `const login() => {`
   `// After login success`
   `const {state: {referrer}} = location;`
   `history.push(referrer)`
   `};`

Check the official docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Answer (score 1):

> React Router v3

**Navigating inside components**

You should use `withRouter` decorator when it's necessary to redirect inside a component. The decorator uses context instead of you.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

fucntion Foo(props) {
    props.router.push('/users/16');
}

export default withRouter(Foo);
```

> withRouter(Component, [options])
>
> A HoC (higher-order component) that wraps another component to enhance
>   its props with router props.
>
> withRouterProps = {
>      ...componentProps,
>      router,
>      params,
>      location,
>      routes
>   }
>
> Pass in your component and it will return the
>   wrapped component.
>
> You can explicit specify router as a prop to the wrapper component to
>   override the router object from context.

Answer (score -13):

In your store:

```
data.router.transitionTo('user');
```

And router has:

`"Route name="user" handler={User}"`

User is route handler