# react router - Redirection after login

Tags: react-router

Could you please help me in understanding  the redirection mechanism I could use with latest version of **react router ( v1.1.0 )** . I would like to redirect to a `url` depending on the success or failure of **user login** .
I have tried to do the following
First created a history using.

```
let history = createBrowserHistory();
```

then tried to push the state using

```
history.pushState(null, 'abc')
```

Nothing is happening. Could you please let me know the correct way to do transitions .From the docs I understood that `transitionTo()` API is not present in the latest versions.
It will be great If you could point to a simple working example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic redirect after login with react-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594720/automatic-redirect-after-login-with-react-router)

Comment: simple way https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916596/3966458

Answer (score 42):

Wanted to update this thread because I spent a good amount of time digging around on this. In React Router 2.0.x, `replaceState` is deprecated in favor of replace. See here for details: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.0.0/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors

The correct way to do this would be something like this:

```js
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!userExists()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/signin',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="protectedRoute" component={Protected} onEnter={requireAuth} />
      <Route path="signin" component={SignIn} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Then, in the SignIn component, you can redirect after a successful sign in like this:

```js
signInFunction({params}, (err, res) => {
  // Now in the sign in callback
  if (err)
    alert("Please try again")
  else {
    const location = this.props.location
    if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
      browserHistory.push(location.state.nextPathname)
    } else {
      browserHistory.push('/')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is the better answer than the accepted. +1 for the signin function.

Comment: these React repos keep migrating! https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.0.0/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors

Comment: onEnter no longer exists on react-router-4. You should use <Route render={ ... } /> to get your desired functionality. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 19):

You can register "hooks" on your routes that get triggered when you enter and leave the routes. Check out the documentation for [onEnter and onLeave hooks](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks).

There is also an [example of requiring auth](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) on a route and redirecting to a different path if the user is not logged in.

Here's a snippet taken from the require auth example within [app.js](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js):

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replaceState) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn())
    replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login')
}

// And from the route configuration, use the requireAuth function in onEnter...
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

The `nextState` and `replaceState` arguments are objects from [rackt/history](https://github.com/rackt/history) and get injected into the method you pass into onEnter.

Comment: Thanks .One more query . Is <IndexRoute> in react router equivalent to a view in angular ?

Comment: Might consider using new terminology in your response given the buzz around [React Hooks](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/68) as of late.

Answer (score 11):

> **React Router v4.2**

I am using **React-16.2** & **React-router-4.2**

and I get solution by this
 `this.props.history.push("/");`

**My working code:**

```
    .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.status == 200){
                this.props.history.push("/");
                console.log('Successfully Login');
          }
        })
```

I was following this document [redirect-on-login-and-logout](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/redirect-on-login-and-logout.html)

Comment: Work like charm

Comment: my not working though path get updated but not not loading '/' path

Answer (score 9):

@terranmoccasin 's answer is correct. However there is a common need very few examples address.

Let's say you need to secure several routes (dashboard1, dashboard2, ...).  How do you redirect back to the original page once you log in successfully? In other words, what do you do with `{nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}`?

Here's what I do in `./containers/LoginContainer.js`:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nextPathname: state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.state.nextPathname,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  changeLocationOnSignIn: (nextPathname) => {
    dispatch(push(nextPathname));
  },
});
```

and in `./components/Login.js`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // user signed in or signed up, assuming redux. you may use this elsewhere.
  if (nextProps.user.status === 'authenticated' && nextProps.user.user &&
     !nextProps.user.error) {
       this.props.changeLocationOnSignIn(this.props.nextPathname);
  }
```

React-router 2.4.0 (April 2016) introduced withRouter which creates a HOC. However it wraps React.createClass, not a JS class. I haven't been able to get it working with redux-form, etc. Besides I think the above code is easier to comprehend.

Comment: In reference to @justabuzz, I should mention I was using Redux and I wanted the redirection to be logged with Redux. Otherwise push() is OK.

Answer (score 7):

i want just share the actual answer at 2020 year. 
The main way for storing previous location in state is the same. But onEnter was removed from library. Now we can use AuthRoute as in the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow):

```js
<AuthRoute exact path="/food">
  <Food />
</AuthRoute>
<Route exact path="/login">
  <Login />
</Route>
```

```js
const AuthRoute = ({ children, isAuthorized, ...rest }) => {
  const loginLink = usePrepareLink({
    to: "/login",
    isRelativePath: true
  });

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={({ location }) =>
      isAuthorized ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          ...loginLink,
          state: { from: location }
        }} />
      )
    } />
  );
};
```

and we can use the state to restore previouse URL after login

```js
const onSignIn = useCallback(() => {
  setIsAuthorized(value);
  const link = (state && state.from) || "/restore-prevented-route";
  history.replace(link);
}, [setIsAuthorized, value, history, state]);
```

The details you can find [here](https://youtu.be/VI3Mo6FJCZA) (or [RU](https://youtu.be/7Ot95R_TP4g))

Answer (score 4):

#### This helps me.

[Redirect to Login After Logout](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/redirect-on-login-and-logout.html)

1. `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";`
2. `const history = useHistory();`
3. `history.push("/login");`

Answer (score 1):

`onEnter` no longer exists on `react-router-4`, You can make use of `<Route render={ ... } />` to achieve the same functionality.

Here is an example of the same.

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/dashboard" render={() => (isAuth() ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <DashboardRoutes />)} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
</React.Fragment>
```

`isAuth()` in my case is a function that basically check whether we have the auth token or not and returns true/false based on that.

```
function isLoggedIn() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnSz mentions I too had issues with using withRouter. Instead I did it as instructed here:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#programmatic-navigation

```
const RouteComponent = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  someHandler() {
    this.context.router.push(...)
  }
})
```

Basically:

1. Define contextType
2. Use this.context.router.push(...)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a condition for the success and failure. Then use the `useNavigate` hook.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function useLogoutTimer() {
  const userIsInactive = useFakeInactiveUser();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userIsInactive) {
      fake.logout();
      navigate("/url");
    }
  }, [userIsInactive]);
}
```

Read more: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Answer (score 0):

After login success message, just one line code just add your page link to redirect

```
alert("Login  Successfully");

window.location.replace("/PageLink");
```