# How to push to History in React Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In the current version of React Router (v3) I can accept a server response and use `browserHistory.push` to go to the appropriate response page. However, this isn't available in v4, and I'm not sure what the appropriate way to handle this is.

In this example, using Redux, *components/app-product-form.js* calls `this.props.addProduct(props)` when a user submits the form. When the server returns a success, the user is taken to the Cart page.

```
// actions/index.js
export function addProduct(props) {
  return dispatch =>
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/cart`, props, config)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: types.AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        browserHistory.push('/cart'); // no longer in React Router V4
      });
}
```

How can I make a redirect to the Cart page from function for React Router v4?

Comment: Just to add to this from the last solution offered and from suggestions in React Router's issues on GitHub, using the `context` to pass what you need manually is a "no go".  Unless I am a library author, there shouldn't be a need to use it. In fact, Facebook recommends against it.

Comment: @Chris  did you find a solution for this ? i need push to a different component in action , same as you have explained here

Comment: @Mr.G, sadly I have not. Last I read was the React Training team that maintains React Router has a redux package available. I haven't had any luck making it work, and they haven't put much work into resolving it.

Comment: Why can't we use windows.location.href= URL? Is there anything wrong in using it to change the URL and redirect?

Comment: I don't see why not, but the option for using `history` also works for React Native as an option as well an addition option of supporting legacy browsers.

Comment: @Shan you would loose application state i believe if you location.href. also its is not mobile friendly.

Comment: Using @Shan's suggestion ex., ( windows.location.href=("/") ) with zero issues on mobile. working as intended. *losing application state in my specific use case is a non issue.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

You can use the `history` methods outside of your components. Try by the following way.

First, create a `history` object used [the history package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history):

```js
// src/history.js

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then wrap it in `<Router>` (**please note**, you should use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`):

```js
// src/index.jsx

// ...
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Change your current location from any place, for example:

```js
// src/actions/userActionCreators.js

// ...
import history from '../history';

export function login(credentials) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return loginRemotely(credentials)
      .then((response) => {
        // ...
        history.push('/');
      });
  };
}
```

---

**UPD**: You can also see a slightly different example in [React Router FAQ](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components).

Comment: I have tried to do exactly as what @OlegBelostotsky said, but after `history.push('some path')`, the URL changes but the page does not change. I have to put `window.location.reload()` after it in some parts of my code just to make it work. However, in one instance I have to keep the redux state tree, and reloading destroys it. Any other solution?

Comment: @idunno Try use the `withRouter` higher-order component.

Comment: This threw me an error stating: createBrowserHistory is not a function. What can i do?

Comment: @AKJ Maybe `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'; export default createHistory();` will be work.

Comment: I find it more logical to use a simple class with methods for route navigation than using the react-router components. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: not working for me. url got updated but component did not render.

Comment: I went through the below link and tried out the withRouter higher-order component..  but it didn't work for me.. [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) this solution provided by @OlegBelostotsky did the trick

Comment: Sorry for the downvote :). While this should also work, the correct way to handle this is how Chris answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/491075.

Comment: is the default behaviour, when you push something to the history, that you get immediately redirected to the last pushed route?

Comment: I had similar problem every redirect was putting whole URL address instead of relative one. Just using createBrowserHistory(); not createBrowserHistory(#something here#); solved my issues!

Comment: react native web,side menu item click for refresh dashboard home,same like for react-native run android--this.props.navigation.navigate({ key: Math.random() * 10000, routeName: "DashBoard", params: id}) same this from web app.

Comment: make sure you are using the correct version of history as indicated in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history). I had a similar issue as @sdabrutas (url pushed to history but page doesn't change) when using history v5 with react router v5. Downgrading history to v4 solved the issue entirely.

Comment: Upvoted comment by @adamgy because this is the correct answer to the question posed/implied: ***how to access history outside of any React component*** However, you have to use history v4 with react-router v5 or history v5 with react-router v6, otherwise it will seem like nothing is working.

Answer (score 390):

React Router v4 is fundamentally different from v3 (and earlier) and you cannot do `browserHistory.push()` like you used to.

[This discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059) seems related if you want more info:

> - Creating a new `browserHistory` won't work because `<BrowserRouter>` creates its own history instance, and listens for changes on that. So a different instance will change the url but not update the `<BrowserRouter>`.
> - `browserHistory` is not exposed by react-router in v4, only in v2.

---

Instead you have a few options to do this:

- #### Use the `withRouter` high-order component

  Instead you should use the `withRouter` high order component, and wrap that to the component that will push to history. For example:

  ```js
  import React from "react";
  import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

  class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    myFunction() {
      this.props.history.push("/some/Path");
    }
    ...
  }
  export default withRouter(MyComponent);
  ```

  Check out the [**official documentation**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) for more info:

  > You can get access to the [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object’s properties and the closest [`<Route>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)'s [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will re-render its component every time the route changes with the same props as [`<Route>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) render props: `{ match, location, history }`.

---

- #### Use the `context` API

  Using the context might be one of the easiest solutions, but being an experimental API it is unstable and unsupported. Use it only when everything else fails. Here's an example:

  ```js
  import React from "react";
  import PropTypes from "prop-types";

  class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      router: PropTypes.object
    }
    constructor(props, context) {
       super(props, context);
    }
    ...
    myFunction() {
      this.context.router.history.push("/some/Path");
    }
    ...
  }
  ```

  Have a look at the [**official documentation**](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) on context:

  > If you want your application to be stable, don't use context. It is an experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of React.
  >
  > If you insist on using context despite these warnings, try to isolate your use of context to a small area and avoid using the context API directly when possible so that it's easier to upgrade when the API changes.

Comment: Yes I did try it. Thanks for asking. :-)  So how do you get the context into this action function? So far, it's coming up as undefined.

Comment: I have been researching this topic for a few days now and have not been able to get this to work. Even using the example above I keep getting router is undefined in the context.  I am currently using react v15.5.10, react-router-dom v4.1.1, prop-types 15.5.10.  The documentation around this is sparse and not very clear.

Comment: @Stu this should work `this.context.router.history.push('/path');`

Comment: I believe @MichaelHorogjanski's answer is correct, especially since React's team states not to use context for stability reasons.

Comment: @SILENT correct. This is already stated at the bottom of my answer. Hence why I have 2 methods posted ;)

Comment: @Chris Indeed, if you try to instantiate history object and use it by yourself it will change the url but will not render component - as you mentioned above. But, how to use "history.push" outside of the component and force component render as well?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked which is how to access history.push OUTSIDE of a component.  Using withRouter or the context are not options for when outside of a component.

Comment: why does PropTypes.object have to be specified? I thought PropTypes were only for future developers?

Comment: context API now officially supported by React; so is it  safe to use now ?

Comment: Its a shame React Router has the name "react" in it. Leads people to think its the official router.

Comment: As of React 16.3 the context API isn't experimental anymore. React's blog post [React v16.3.0: New lifecycles and context API](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html) for more info on the release.

Comment: I'dd like to add that this approach also makes the component easier to test, since it's not tight coupled to the global `browserHistory` api, and it relies on the api passed by props, which can easily be mocked/stubbed/spied on.

Answer (score 121):

Now with react-router v5 you can use the useHistory hook like this:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

read more at: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: Is there any specific way I need to set this up, I'm calling the following `let history = useHistory();` but getting an `Object is not callable` error, when I tried seeing what useHistory is `console.log(useHistory)` it shows up as undefined.
using `"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"`

Comment: @steff_bdh you need to update it in yout package.json file to "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1" and run 'npm install'

Comment: Nice, but can't use hook inside redux action classes as they are not React component/function

Comment: How would you use this for redirection upon login using (async). Here's the question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154408/redirect-page-upon-login-using-react-router-v5-and-redux-toolkit

Comment: To quote React: "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a **function component**."

Comment: Check if there is <Router> tag inside of the component you're calling useHistory(). If it does, move <Router> tag to index.js instead (wrapping from parent component). Why ? I don't know. It seems like an issue of the library. @steff_bdh

Answer (score 44):

Simplest way in React Router 4 is to use

```
this.props.history.push('/new/url');
```

But to use this method, your **existing** component should have access to `history` object. We can get access by

1. If your component is linked to `Route` directly, then your component already has access to `history` object.

   eg:

   ```
   <Route path="/profile" component={ViewProfile}/>
   ```

   Here `ViewProfile` has access to `history`.
2. If not connected to `Route` directly.

   eg:

   ```
   <Route path="/users" render={() => <ViewUsers/>}
   ```

   Then we have to use `withRouter`, a heigher order fuction to warp the existing component.

   **Inside** `ViewUsers` component

   - `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`
   - `export default withRouter(ViewUsers);`

   That's it now, your `ViewUsers` component has access to `history` object.

**UPDATE**

`2`- in this scenario, pass all route `props` to your component, and then we can access `this.props.history` from the component even without a `HOC`

eg:

```
<Route path="/users" render={props => <ViewUsers {...props} />}
```

Comment: Excellent! Your second method also did the trick for me, as my component (which needs access to `this.props.history`) comes from a HOC, which means that it is not directly linked to the `Route`, as you explain.

Comment: Note that when you use `history.push`, the second argument is the state (see https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history). For my case, I did `history.push('/same/route/I/am/currently/on', this.state)` right after an operation that updated the state. That causes the new state to get added to the history stack. Then in `compoenntDidMount()` I check if `this.props.location.state` is defined, and if it is, call `this.setState(this.props.location.state)` to bring back the state when I get back to my component.

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question how to use history outside a component

Answer (score 27):

This is how I did it:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Link extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onLogout = this.onLogout.bind(this);
    }
    onLogout() {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Your Links</h1>
                <button onClick={this.onLogout}>Logout</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Use `this.props.history.push('/cart');` to redirect to cart page it will be saved in history object.

Enjoy, Michael.

Comment: Yes, it looks like within the components you can push just fine. The only way to affect navigating outside a component is with redirect.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked which is how to access history.push OUTSIDE of a component.  Using this.props.history is not an option for when outside of a component.

Answer (score 23):

According to [React Router v4 documentation - Redux Deep Integration session](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/redux-integration/deep-integration)

Deep integration is needed to:

> "be able to navigate by dispatching actions"

However, they recommend this approach as an alternative to the "deep integration":

> "Rather than dispatching actions to navigate you can pass the history object provided to route components to your actions and navigate with it there."

So you can wrap your component with the withRouter high order component:

`export default withRouter(connect(null, { actionCreatorName })(ReactComponent));`

which will pass the history API to props. So you can call the action creator passing the history as a param. For example, inside your ReactComponent:

```
onClick={() => {
  this.props.actionCreatorName(
    this.props.history,
    otherParams
  );
}}
```

Then, inside your actions/index.js:

```
export function actionCreatorName(history, param) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: SOME_ACTION,
      payload: param.data
    });
    history.push("/path");
  };
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Nasty question, took me quite a lot of time, but eventually, I solved it this way:

Wrap your container with `withRouter` and pass history to your action in  `mapDispatchToProps` function. In action use history.push('/url') to navigate.

Action:

```
export function saveData(history, data) {
  fetch.post('/save', data)
     .then((response) => {
       ...
       history.push('/url');
     })
};
```

Container:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    save: (data) => dispatch(saveData(ownProps.history, data))}
};
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container));
```

This is valid for **React Router v4.x**.

Comment: Thanks, your withRouter solution works with typescript but its quite slow compared with earlier ```import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'```  any idea please?

Answer (score 9):

I offer one more solution in case it is worthful for someone else.

I have a `history.js` file where I have the following:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createHistory()
history.pushLater = (...args) => setImmediate(() => history.push(...args))
export default history
```

Next, on my Root where I define my router I use the following:

```
import history from '../history'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
       <Switch>
        ...
       </Switch>
      </Router>
     </Provider>
    )
   }
  }
```

Finally, on my `actions.js` I import History and make use of pushLater

```
import history from './history'
export const login = createAction(
...
history.pushLater({ pathname: PATH_REDIRECT_LOGIN })
...)
```

This way, I can push to new actions after API calls.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

`this.context.history.push` will not work.

I managed to get push working like this:

```
static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.props.auth.success) {
        this.context.router.history.push("/some/Path")
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked which is how to access history.push OUTSIDE of a component. Using this.context is not an option for when outside of a component.

Answer (score 7):

**Be careful** that don't use `react-router@5.2.0` or `react-router-dom@5.2.0` with `history@5.0.0`. URL will update after `history.push` or any other push to history instructions but navigation is not working with `react-router`. use `npm install history@4.10.1` to change the history version. see [React router not working after upgrading to v 5](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804#issue-639628770).

I think this problem is happening when push to history happened. for example using `<NavLink to="/apps">` facing a problem in NavLink.js that consume `<RouterContext.Consumer>`. `context.location` is changing to an object with action and location properties when the push to history occurs. So `currentLocation.pathname` is null to match the path.

Answer (score 6):

In this case you're passing props to your thunk. So you can simply call

```
props.history.push('/cart')
```

If this isn't the case you can still pass history from your component

```
export function addProduct(data, history) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post('/url', data).then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: types.AUTH_USER })
      history.push('/cart')
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with the same topic.
I'm using react-router-dom 5, Redux 4 and BrowserRouter.
I prefer function based components and hooks.

You define your component like this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const Component = () => {
  ...
  const history = useHistory();
  dispatch(myActionCreator(otherValues, history));
};
```

And your action creator is following

```
const myActionCreator = (otherValues, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  ...
  history.push("/path");
}
```

You can of course have simpler action creator if async is not needed

Comment: It's great. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Redux, then I would recommend using npm package [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux#installation). It allows you to dispatch Redux store navigation actions.

You have to create store as described in their [Readme file](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux#installation).

**The easiest use case:**

```js
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

this.props.dispatch(push('/second page'));
```

**Second use case with Container/Component:**

Container:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

import Form from '../components/Form';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  changeUrl: url => dispatch(push(url)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Form extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.changeUrl('/secondPage');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>Readme file
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does **not** work with react-router-redux unless you are using the `next` version, which is still under development at this moment!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my hack (this is my root-level file, with a little redux mixed in there - though I'm not using `react-router-redux`):

```
const store = configureStore()
const customHistory = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: config.urlBasename || ''
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={customHistory}>
      <Route component={({history}) => {
        window.appHistory = history
        return (
          <App />
        )
      }}/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I can then use `window.appHistory.push()` anywhere I want (for example, in my redux store functions/thunks/sagas, etc) I had hoped I could just use `window.customHistory.push()` but for some reason `react-router` never seemed to update even though the url changed. But this way I have the EXACT instance `react-router` uses. I don't love putting stuff in the global scope, and this is one of the few things I'd do that with. But it's better than any other alternative I've seen IMO.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this by using `bind()`.  I wanted to click a button in `index.jsx`, post some data to the server, evaluate the response, and redirect to `success.jsx`.  Here's how I worked that out...

`index.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { postData } from "../../scripts/request"

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        this.postData = postData.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        const data = {
            "first_name": "Test",
            "last_name": "Guy",
            "email": "test@test.com"
        }

        this.postData("person", data)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Main">
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Test Post</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main
```

`request.js`:

```
import { post } from "./fetch"

export const postData = function(url, data) {
    // post is a fetch() in another script...
    post(url, data)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.status === "ok") {
                this.props.history.push("/success")
            }
        })
}
```

`success.jsx`:

```
import React from "react"

const Success = () => {
    return (
        <div className="Success">
            Hey cool, got it.
        </div>
    )
}

export default Success
```

So by binding `this` to `postData` in `index.jsx`, I was able to access `this.props.history` in `request.js`... then I can reuse this function in different components, just have to make sure I remember to include `this.postData = postData.bind(this)` in the `constructor()`.

Answer (score 4):

so the way I do it is:
- instead of redirecting using `history.push`, I just use `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom`
When using this component you can just pass `push=true`, and it will take care of the rest

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
class Example extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      redirectTo: '/test/path'
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { redirectTo } = this.state;

    return <Redirect to={{pathname: redirectTo}} push={true}/>
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the correct which does not break react render cycle

Answer (score 3):

Use Callback. It worked for me!

```
export function addProduct(props, callback) {
  return dispatch =>
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/cart`, props, config)
    .then(response => {
    dispatch({ type: types.AUTH_USER });
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
    callback();
  });
}
```

In component, you just have to add the callback

```
this.props.addProduct(props, () => this.props.history.push('/cart'))
```

Answer (score 2):

React router V4 now allows the history prop to be used as below:

```
this.props.history.push("/dummy",value)
```

The value then can be accessed wherever the location prop is available as 
`state:{value}` not component state.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked which is how to access history.push OUTSIDE of a component. Using this.props.history is not an option for when outside of a component.

Answer (score 2):

As we have a history already included in react router 5, we can access the same with reference

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
   const routerRef = React.useRef();
   const onProductNav = () => {
       const history = routerRef.current.history;
       history.push("product");
   }
return (
    <BrowserRouter ref={routerRef}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/product">
                <ProductComponent />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <HomeComponent />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

step one wrap your app in Router

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now my entire App will have access to BrowserRouter. Step two I import Route and then pass down those props. Probably in one of your main files.

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

//lots of code here

//somewhere in my render function

    <Route
      exact
      path="/" //put what your file path is here
      render={props => (
      <div>
        <NameOfComponent
          {...props} //this will pass down your match, history, location objects
        />
      </div>
      )}
    />
```

Now if I run console.log(this.props) in my component js file that I should get something that looks like this

```
{match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, //other stuff }
```

Step 2 I can access the history object to change my location

```
//lots of code here relating to my whatever request I just ran delete, put so on

this.props.history.push("/") // then put in whatever url you want to go to
```

Also I'm just a coding bootcamp student, so I'm no expert, but I know you can also you use

```
window.location = "/" //wherever you want to go
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but when I tested that out it reloaded the entire page which I thought defeated the entire point of using React.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `Router` with its own `browserHistory`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const ExtBrowserRouter = ({children}) => (
  <Router history={history} >
  { children }
  </Router>
);

export default ExtBrowserRouter
```

Next, on your Root where you define your `Router`, use the following:

```
import React from 'react';       
import { /*BrowserRouter,*/ Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

//Use 'ExtBrowserRouter' instead of 'BrowserRouter'
import ExtBrowserRouter from './ExtBrowserRouter'; 
...

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ExtBrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            ...
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}  />
            ...
          </Switch>
        </ExtBrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Finally, import `history` where you need it and use it:

```
import { history } from '../routers/ExtBrowserRouter';
...

export function logout(){
  clearTokens();      
  history.push('/login'); //WORKS AS EXPECTED!
  return Promise.reject('Refresh token has expired');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this as i do it for login and manny different things

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.login=this.login.bind(this)
  }


  login(){
this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }


render() {

    return (

   <div>
    <button onClick={this.login}>login</login>
    </div>

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Step 1*/
myFunction(){  this.props.history.push("/home"); }
/**/
 <button onClick={()=>this.myFunction()} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Go 
 Home</button>
```

Comment: No need for any imports !

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use history while passing a function as a value to a Component's prop, with **react-router 4** you can simply destructure the `history` prop in the render attribute of the `<Route/>` Component and then use `history.push()`

```
    <Route path='/create' render={({history}) => (
      <YourComponent
        YourProp={() => {
          this.YourClassMethod()
          history.push('/')
        }}>
      </YourComponent>
    )} />
```

Note: For this to work you should wrap React Router's BrowserRouter Component around your root component (eg.  which might be in index.js)