# this.context.router.push is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am using react router 4.0 version. I am trying to navigate from one component to another on button click. I have implemented react routing for this.
After implementation when i click the navigate button it is giving me error "Uncaught TypeError: this.context.router.push is not a function" and a warning 
"Failed context type: Invalid context `router` of type `object` supplied to `EmpLogin`, expected `function`." Tried a lot but could not make it working. below are my component and routing implementation. Earlier i was using react router 2.0 and browserhistory.push was working.

```
export class EmpLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {

};
}

loginID(e) {
this.setState({loginID: e.target.value});
}

 Password(e) {
this.setState({password: e.target.value});
}

 navigate(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.push('/EmpDetails');
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
    <div >
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.loginID.bind(this)} />
        <input type="password" onChange={this.Password.bind(this)} />  
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
            <button onClick={this.navigate.bind(this)}>feature</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);
 }
 }

  EmpLogin.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
 }

 export default EmpLogin;
```

Routing implementation -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import EmpLogin from './EmpLogin';
import {Router, Route,HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {browserHistory,hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import EmpDetails from './EmpDetails';

ReactDOM.render((
 <HashRouter>
 <div>
  <Route exact path='/' component={EmpLogin}/>
  <Route path='/Emplogin' component={EmpLogin}/>
  <Route path='/EmpDetails' component={EmpDetails} />
  </div>
  </HashRouter>
 ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Did you try changing the contextType to PropTypes.object?

Comment: yes i have tried that but no luck.

Answer (score 28):

The correct way to navigate using context in react-router v4:

```
this.context.router.history.push('/EmpDetails')
```

The new react-router v4 has changed the location of the `push` method when accessing `this.context.router`. `router` now has `history` and `route` as properties and it is within `history` that you will find the allocated method.

Also, if you are using the latest react version 15.5.0, propTypes have been removed into a separate package and you can get them with:

```
npm install prop-types --save
```

or

```
yarn add prop-types
```

This is written for documentation reasons. Other users answers did not successfully solve the issue, and as I had this issue I decided to fill it in for the convenience of future developers.

Comment: In case `this.context.router` is undefined (due to updates), you can find a more thorough discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4

Answer (score 2):

From the error it seems that it is looking for `router` as an object:

Try this:

```
EmpLogin.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Also you can try `transitionTo` instead of `push()` along with the above method

```
this.context.router.transitionTo('/EmpDetails');
```

Comment: i have tried this but it still giving me error "Uncaught TypeError: this.context.router.push is not a function" but warning gets out

Comment: yes, i can use.. i have already tried this but same error i am getting for this too. transitionTo is not a function

Comment: Can you console.log(this.context.router) and see what all options you see

Comment: in console i am getting one object. in the object i am getting history and route.

Comment: any solution to this

Comment: @Dlucidone Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/trying-to-change-the-routing-url-based-on-a-specific-condition-in-react/44128108#44128108

Comment: @Shubham: if i want send data through this `router.push({pathname:"/",data:{data:this.state.auth }});` how to retrive the transmitted data in the new redirected component

Answer (score 0):

you should use browserHistory from react-router instead...

```
  browserHistory.push('/EmpDetails');
```

Comment: try the suggestion on this... [link](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/808), you might be able to use react-router-dom since your on the 4.0..

Answer (score 0):

I have mixed your answers. And then I have succeeded on react 16.5.2!

Install *prop-types*

```
npm i prop-types --save
```

Import *PropTypes* in my *NavMenu.js*

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Set *contextTypes*

```
NavMenu.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Finally use *this.context.router.history.push*

```
<MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
  <span onClick={() => this.context.router.history.push("/")}>
    Home
  </span>
</MenuItem>
```