# Programmatically Navigate using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am developing an application in which I check if the user is not `loggedIn`. I have to display the login form, else `dispatch` an `action` that would change the route and load other component. Here is my code:

```js
render() {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        // dispatch an action to change the route
    }
    // return login component
    <Login />
}
```

How can I achieve this as I cannot change states inside the `render` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 43):

Considering you are using `react-router v4`

Use your component with `withRouter` and use `history.push` from props to change the route. You need to make use of `withRouter` only when your component is not receiving the `Router` props, this may happen in cases when your component is a nested child of a component rendered by the Router and you haven't passed the Router props to it or when the component is not linked to the Router at all and is rendered as a separate component from the Routes.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
     ...
     componenDidMount() {
        // get isLoggedIn from localStorage or API call
        if (isLoggedIn) {
             // dispatch an action to change the route
             this.props.history.push('/home');
        }
     }
     render() {
         // return login component
         return <Login />
    }
}


export default withRouter(App);
```

> **Important Note**
>
> If you are using `withRouter` to prevent updates from being blocked by
>   `shouldComponentUpdate`, it is important that `withRouter` wraps the
>   component that implements `shouldComponentUpdate`. For example, when
>   using Redux:
>
> // This gets around `shouldComponentUpdate`
>
> ```
> withRouter(connect(...)(MyComponent))
> ```
>
> // This does not
>
> ```
> connect(...)(withRouter(MyComponent))
> ```

or you could use Redirect

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
     ...
     render() {
         if(isLoggedIn) {
              return <Redirect to="/home"/>
         }
         // return login component
         return <Login />
    }
}
```

With `react-router v2 or react-router v3`, you can make use of `context` to dynamically change the route like

```
class App extends React.Component {
     ...
     render() {
         if (isLoggedIn) {
             // dispatch an action to change the route
             this.context.router.push('/home');
         }
         // return login component
         return <Login />
    }
}

App.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
export default App;
```

or use

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
browserHistory.push('/some/path');
```

Comment: i am using react-router v 2

Comment: @GauravMehta consider upgrading to v3 or 4.. Will give you more options

Comment: Updated for v2.0

Comment: this.context.router returns undefined

Comment: Did you add contextTypes on you component

Comment: Why is this so complicated ? I wish we could just `history.pushState` from anywhere...

Comment: @LoremIpsum, I don't think its complicated. Its pretty simple. Are you facing any difficulties with it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no no, thank you, but I'm just curious about the design choices. Why doesn't the router simply listen to state changes ? This way, links wouldn't be tied to react-router (i.e. simple `<a/>` elements would be enough) for instance...

Comment: @LoremIpsum, well I suppose its because not all components will be Directly linked to the Route and it would be better off to not force a component to be aware of all Route properties if it doesn't need. and this is where I think withRouter comes in handy

Comment: @LoremIpsum, my answer on this question describes how you can use a create a more natural connection to the router.

Comment: `browserHistory` option doesn't seem to work anymore (v4.3.1). Original `withRouter` + `this.props.history.push(...)` does though

Comment: @zlog, the answer clearly mentions the versions and their respective solutions

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. It was just a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

In react-router version 4:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

const Example = () => (

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    <OtherComponent />

  } else {

    <Router>
      <Redirect push to="/login" />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    </Router>

  }
)

const Login = () => (
    <h1>Form Components</h1>
    ...
)

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to handle this using Thunk-style asynchronous actions (which are safe/allowed to have side-effects).

If you use Thunk, you can inject the same `history` object into both your `<Router>` component and Thunk actions using `thunk.withExtraArgument`, like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const history = createBrowserHistory()

const middlewares = applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({history}))
const store = createStore(appReducer, middlewares)

render(
  <Provider store={store}
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="*" component={CatchAll} />
    </Router
  </Provider>,
appDiv)
```

Then in your action-creators, you will have a `history` instance that is safe to use with ReactRouter, so you can just trigger a regular Redux event if you're not logged in:

```
// meanwhile... in action-creators.js
export const notLoggedIn = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {history}) => {
    history.push(`/login`)
  }
}
```

Another advantage of this is that the url is easier to handle, now, so we can put redirect info on the query string, etc.

You can try still doing this check in your Render methods, but if it causes problems, you might consider doing it in `componentDidMount`, or elsewhere in the lifecycle (although also I understand the desire to stick with Stateless Functional Compeonents!)

You can still use Redux and `mapDispatchToProps` to inject the action creator into your comptonent, so your component is still only loosely connected to Redux.

Comment: OK, this looks nice. But what is `CatchAll` and do we really need the *history* library?

Comment: It's been a while since I posted this answer, but I'm guessing I plucked this example out of some production code and slimmed it down. Your app's `Route`s would go inside the router. `CatchAll` here is just an example to show where the `Route`s would go.

The `history` library is [already being used by React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/package.json#L29) if you're using it in history mode. This approach gives us programmatic access to the history API from within our _actions_, as opposed to `withRouter`, which lets us use the history API from components.

Answer (score 2):

This is my handle `loggedIn`. `react-router v4`

PrivateRoute is allow enter `path` if user is loggedIn and save the token to `localStorge`

```
    function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
     return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={props => (localStorage.token) ? <Component {...props} /> : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/signin',
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
          )
          }
        />
      );
    }
```

Define all paths in your app in here

```
export default (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
      <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
);
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55451941/edit) some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Those who are facing issues in implementing this on **react-router v4**. Here is a working solution for navigating through the react app programmatically.

history.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export default createHistory()
```

App.js OR Route.jsx. Pass history as a prop to your Router.

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'
...
<Router history={history}>
 <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
</Router>
```

You can use `push()` to navigate.

```
import history from './history' 

...

render() {
     if (isLoggedIn) {
         history.push('/test') // this should change the url and re-render Test component
     }
     // return login component
     <Login />
}
```

All thanks to this comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3498#issuecomment-301057248

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){ 

    return (
        <div>  
            { this.props.redirect ? <Redirect to="/" /> :'' } 
            <div>
                add here component codes
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use **connected-react-router** https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router 
which helps to perform navigation even from reducers/actions if you want.
it is well documented and easy to configure

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `history` within stateless functional component, using withRouter following way (needed to ignore typescript warning):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...

type Props = { myProp: boolean };

// @ts-ignore
export const MyComponent: FC<Props> = withRouter(({ myProp, history }) => {

...

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; //with v6

export default function Component() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  navigate.push('/path');
}
```

I had this issue and just solved it with the new useNavigate hook in version 6 of react-router-dom

Comment: The OP is using v2, your arnswer is not helpful in the case.