# With React-Router-4, how to programmatically set the index route `/`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

With React-Router-4 how can I programmatically set the index route `/`

For example, if the user is not authenticated, this should trigger:

```
<Route path="/" component={LandingPage}>
```

If the user is authenticated:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

For your information on [PrivateRoute](https://github.com/timscott/react-devise/blob/ab1dfe5ae3062e1ce8b7e0181e7a193a45b7a4af/src/routing/PrivateRoute.jsx)

### Updated attempt

```
const WithMainLayout = ({component: Component, ...more}) => {
  return <Route {...more} render={props => {
    return (
      <MainLayout {...props}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }}/>;
};

const isLoggedIn = () => {
  console.log('do it')
  return true;
};


....

<WithMainLayout exact path="/" component={Home} render={() => (
  isLoggedIn() ? (
    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
  ) : (
    <Home />
  )
)}/>
```

See above attempt, for some reason, the `console.log` is not outputting anything in the isLoggedIn func.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/trying-to-change-the-routing-url-based-on-a-specific-condition-in-react/44128108#44128108

Comment: ya, trying it now...

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri See above attempt, for some reason, the console.log is not outputting anything in the isLoggedIn func.

Comment: Buddy, If you pass render prop to WithMainLayout function and then pass it to props with {...more} and then write `<Route {...more} render={props => {`. I suppose you render defined in Route overwrites your passed render prop and hence it doesn't log anything in `isLoggedIn()`

Comment: not sure I follow, does that mean this idea won't work?

Comment: What it means is that the prop render to WithMainLayout is overwritten by your custom implementation to <Route> in WithMainLayout. So this won't work.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri is there a way to merge the render? other ideas? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147626/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-anapprentice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your Updated Code the problem is that you return

`<Route {...more} render={props => {`

so what essentially happens is that the `render` prop passed on to the `WithMainLayout` component which is available with `{...more}` is overwritten by you custom prop and hence `isLoggedIn` is never called.

The solution is simple, you can just interchange the `{...more}` and `render={props => {}}` and also wrap your Home component with `WithMainLayout` so that it doesn't miss the Layout

You code will look like

```
const WithMainLayout = ({component: Component, ...more}) => {
  return <Route render={props => {
    return (
      <MainLayout {...props}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }}  {...more} />;
};

const isLoggedIn = () => {
  console.log('do it')
  return true;
};


....

<WithMainLayout exact path="/" component={Home} render={() => (
  isLoggedIn() ? (
    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
  ) : (
    <WithMainLayout component={Home} />
  )
)}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `history` prop. You can read about it here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Essentially you wrap your component in the `withRouter` HOC, and it will pass the `history` prop to your component which you'll see here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter. It blends very well with React Recompose. I modified the "basic example" of the react router docs as an example here of using withRouter with the `history` prop

```
// create-react-app test && cd test && npm i && npm install react-router-dom
// replace contents of App.js then `npm run start`
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

class BasicExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <hr/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={withRouter(Home)}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const {history} = this.props;
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      history.push("/about")
    }
    console.log(history)
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>To about</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

export default BasicExample;
```

If you're creating the link in your JSX, use the `Link` component, which looks like this

```
<Link to="/">...</Link>
```

If you're doing it inside of your `PrivateRoute` component, I think what you want is something more like the `Redirect` component: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      props.isAuthorized ? (
        <Component {...props}/>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }}/>
      )
    )}/>)
```

Comment: See above attempt, for some reason, the console.log is not outputting anything in the isLoggedIn func.

Answer (score 1):

I would put on `onEnter` method on the `IndexRoute`, and programmatically send the user to the correct location as needed:

```
<IndexRoute onEnter={handlePath}>
```

where the handler looks something like this, with `userIsAutheticaed` is replace by the appropriate code:

```
function handlePath(route, replace) {
   if (userIsAuthenticated) {
          replace('/dashboard');
   } else {
          replace('/');
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks but IndexRoute is not included in react-router-4

Comment: You could just use a normal route then, it doesn't really matter. You could have the route be `/` and then redirect the user away to `/dashboard` when appropriate. Same idea

Comment: thanks but this doesn't seem to be working with react-router-4

Comment: But you don't want to do it in the other way around, or you risk to access (and rendering) a private area