# How to change routes from a component rendered by a <Route> in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am rendering a `Home` component inside a `Route` so that I can pass state in as a prop to the component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            page: 'false'
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' render={()=><Home page={this.state.page}/>} />
                        <Route exact path='/projects' component={Projects} />
                        <Route render={function(){
                            return <p>Not Found</p>
                        }} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Inside the `Home` component, I want to trigger a route change from a function. Because the Component is rendered inside the `Route` the history prop doesn't get passed in and therefore I cannot trigger a route change like so:

```
class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.gotoProjects = this.gotoProjects.bind(this);
    }
    gotoProjects() {
        this.props.history.push('/projects');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.gotoProjects.bind(this)}>Projects</button>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I change routes from a component while still retaining it's props?

**UPDATE**
I've created a History.js using createBrowserHistory

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory()
```

And updated App.js to be

```
import history from '../history';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            page: 'false'
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' render={()=><Home history={history} page={this.state.page}/>} />
                        <Route exact path='/projects' component={Projects} />
                        <Route render={function(){
                            return <p>Not Found</p>
                        }} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

So now when I click the button in `Home` the url goes to /projects but the view is still rendering `Home` instead of `Projects`. How do I render `Projects` after the history.push happens?

Comment: I suppose this is the answer that you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-routing-based-on-a-condition-with-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: I'm not sure how to structure my code properly to use withRouter

Comment: you just need to use withRouter with the component you wanna use history prop with like `export default witRouter(Home);`

Comment: I got a few errors:
index_bundle.js:1834 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Route`.

Comment: what are the few error

Comment: "The error is located at: 
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by App)
    in App"

Comment: instead of creating a custom history and passing it to Home component, just wrap Home component with withRouter HOC and it should be fine, Also make sure you export Home and Projects component and import them properly