# Link to not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactive-programming

I have a situation where on clicking on a div element, the browser should navigate to a different page. In the onClick of this event, I change the value of the state variable and in the Link tag, I pass the values to the next component.

The code is like this-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom' ;
import $ from 'jquery' ;
import {Switch, BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {FullBlog} from './FullBlog.js'


class Author extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      data:this.props.data,
     }
    this.loadBlog=this.loadBlog.bind(this);
  }

  loadBlog(i){
    var data=this.state.data[i];
    this.setState({
     data:data, 
    })

  }

  render(){
   let content=(<p></p>);
    //console.log(this.state.data);
    var data=this.state.data;

     content=( 
        <div>
      <Link to={'/fullblog/${data}'} /><div onClick={this.loadBlog.bind(this,this.props.i)} className="box">
       <div>{this.props.i}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Author}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Book}</div>
        </div>  
       </div>

     )


        return content;
    }
}
```

And the parent class for the same is like this

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {ExpenseApp} from './expense-app.js'
import {Switch, BrowserRouter as Router,Route,hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import {FullBlog} from './FullBlog.js'
class App extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
      <div>
                <Route path='/' render={()=><ExpenseApp data={data}/>}/>
            <Route path='/fullblog' component={FullBlog}/>
        </div>
            </Router>
            )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

After this, I get error as
[image: errror]

Answer (score 0):

`hashHistory` is not available from the `react-router-dom package v4` onwards and has been moved to `history` npm package. You however can make use of `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`

Also with the link component if you want to pass a dynamic value make use of `template literals` instead of having the value within single quotes.

```
<Link to={`/fullblog/${this.props.data}`} />
```

With the use of template literals if `{this.props.data}` has a value `foo` then the link path will be evaluated to `/fullblog/foo` , however if you use single quotes your path will remain `/fullblog/${this.props.data}`

Comment: If I have to use browserhistory as I am trying to implement a dynamic web application, then how can I pass history?

Comment: and what do you mean by template literals

Comment: Why do you want to pass history, if it is to implement dynamic routing  you can see this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-routing-based-on-a-condition-with-react-router/44128108#44128108 See this for template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: what difference will it make, I will be doing the same thing just returning it in a function!The ultimate result will be the same, I guess!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little as to what is happening and what you need

Comment: I just want to navigate to the component fullblog on click of the div, but that is not happening.

Comment: Instead, the div that I click on is disappearing

Comment: Instead of using the Link component you can implement dynamic routing in the loadBlog component as mentions in one of my above comment. Also that div will disappear because onClick you call loadBlog function where you are setting state load to `true` and you are rendering div only on false load value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149892/discussion-between-aayushi-and-shubham-khatri).