# React: Prop Not Displayed in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a prop in react route component as listed below:

```
<Route exact 
       path='/' 
       component={HomePage} 
       display_notification={this.display_notification.bind(this)} 
/>
```

But When I print the props of HomePage I cannot find display_notification.

Please help.

I am using react-router-v4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Route does not recompose props for you, it passes internal location related props only. you need to use the `render={}` API - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

so something like

```
<Route exact 
  path='/' 
  render={() => <HomePage display_notification={this.display_notification} />} />
```

Comment: but if I do that than I cannot access location using props in the component.

Comment: they arrive as arguments to the render func - so `{props => <HomePage foo={props.bar} notification={this.blah} />`

Comment: @sam23, you need to wrap your component with withRouter, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-routing-based-on-a-condition-with-react-router/44128108#44128108