# How to avoid redirecting twice (react-router-redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I am using [the next (5.0.0) version react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) which is compatible with react-router 4.x.

My app has two pages `/login` and `/home`.

I am trying to redirect pages to `/login` if user visits a page not existing. This is my code

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route path="/login" render={() => (
          isSignedIn ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Login />
        )}/>

        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />

        <Redirect to="/login" />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If I remove `<Redirect to="/login" />` and if the user already signed in, when he opens the page `/home`, the app will go to home page directly, which is good.

However, with `<Redirect to="/login" />`, when the user opens the page `/home`, the app will first redirect to `/login`, then goes back to `/home`.

How can I avoid this redirecting twice? Thanks

Comment: Why not configure a route for Home and then redirect to login is the user is not logged in from within Home component

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri, I didn't get it, can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: See this question to check for loggin in Home https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-routing-based-on-a-condition-with-react-router/44128108#44128108 and redirect 

And I mean You can have a route like `<Route path="/home" component={Home}/>`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, actually it is already like that, I just updated. But still does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of `Switch` so that the first matching route is rendered and nothing else

```
import {Switch} from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" render={() => (
          isSignedIn ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Login />
        )}/>

        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />

        <Redirect to="/login" />
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What happens in your case is that even though `/home` matches, the `Redirect` is also executed.

Comment: As I said in my comment, you can keep the logic of redirecting to login in the Home component. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-routing-based-on-a-condition-with-react-router/44128108#44128108