# Redirect to user page after login in with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to redirect to user page after login. This is my code:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/login.scss';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { checkLogin } from './../actions/login.action';

class Login extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };
    this.handleChangeUsername = this.handleChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.wasSuccessful !== this.props.wasSuccessful) {
        this.redirectToUserPage(nextProps.wasSuccessful);
    }
}

redirectToUserPage = () => {
    if (this.props.wasSuccessful) {
        window.location.href = 'localhost:3000/filterableTable';
    }
};

login =() =>  {
    this.props.dispatch(checkLogin(this.state));
};
handleChangeUsername(event) {
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
}
handleChangePassword(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
}
render() {
    console.log('----', this.props.wasSuccessful);
    return (
  <div className={styles.loginForm}>
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChangeUsername} name="username" placeholder="Username" required></input>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChangePassword} name="password" placeholder="Password" required></input>
      <input type="submit"  value="Login" onClick={this.login}></input>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

Login.propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    wasSuccessful: PropTypes.boolean,
};

export default connect((state) => ({
     wasSuccessful: state.login.wasSuccessful
}))(Login);
```

On wasSuccessful the state changess to True, so when i press login, i should be able to redirect to user page.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if (nextProps.wasSuccessful !== this.props.wasSuccessful) {
              this.redirectToUserPage(nextProps.wasSuccessful);
       }
  }
```

I understood that this will be called when the state is changed, so in here i call the function redirectToUserPage.

```
  redirectToUserPage = () => {
      if (this.props.wasSuccessful) {
          window.location.href = 'localhost:3000/filterableTable';
      }
 };
```

I tryed like this, but it doesn't work. Please, help~

Comment: Assuming you are using react-router, See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [hashHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md) from my experience,

```
import {hashHistory} from 'react-router'

  redirectToUserPage = () => {
      if (this.props.wasSuccessful) {
          hashHistory.push('#/filterableTable');
      }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're getting a console error (something like "cannot access wasSuccessful of undefined") because of `this.props.wasSuccessful` inside redirectToUserPage. You're not binding `this` to redirectToUserPage function in constructor. The scope of this has changed from that of Login class to redirectToUserPage's. The `this` inside that function doesnt have props.