# Error with redirect route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to make that when the user login correctly redirects to another screen but does not do it all right...

I change the browser path to which I indicate but I get an error by console that I do not understand because it appears

[image: Image with error]

The component...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Header from '../components/Header/Header.jsx';

import { fetchCompanies } from '../actions/index';
import { loginUserGoogle } from '../actions/login';

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCompanies();
  }

  renderUser () {
    const {name,email,photo}  = this.props.user;
    if (!email) {
      return (
        <h1>User not logged </h1>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        this.props.router.push('/prueba')
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page-home">
        <Header />
        <button onClick={() => this.props.loginUserGoogle()}>LOGIN GOOGLE</button>
        {this.renderUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.userInfo
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchCompanies, loginUserGoogle})(Home);
```

As you can see in the photo, change to the new window but the error comes out by console. How could I solve it?

### EDIT

I use react-router v3

```
"dependencies": {
"antd": "^2.13.8",
"babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
"firebase": "^4.6.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"react-redux": "^5.0.2",
"react-router": "^3.0.1",
"react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-form": "^6.4.3",
"redux-saga": "^0.14.3",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"


},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.6.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.15",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "redux-freeze": "^0.1.5",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the the elements returned by `renderUser` function and hence you shouldn't call the `router.push()` function in the return statement. You can either return `Redirect` element if you are using `react-router v4` like

```
renderUser () {
    const {name,email,photo}  = this.props.user;
    if (!email) {
      return (
        <h1>User not logged </h1>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Redirect to='/prueba' />
      );
    }
  }
```

or just call the function like

```
renderUser () {
    const {name,email,photo}  = this.props.user;
    if (!email) {
      return (
        <h1>User not logged </h1>
      );
    } else {
        this.props.router.push('/prueba')
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried with your solution but... i see this error
Error: <Redirect> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered

Comment: Seems you are not using React-router v4. In that case you should make use of the second approach

Comment: Correct, i use react-router v3.
How can I do so that I do not get the error of the image?

Comment: Specifying routes inside the components is not available in react-router v3 or below. You can instead route dynamically like `else {
        this.props.router.push('/prueba')
    }` . See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: With this solution, same error...
render() {
    const {name,email,photo}  = this.props.user;
    if (email) {
      this.context.router.push('/prueba');
    }
    
    return (
      <div className="page-home">
        <Header />
          <button onClick={this.props.loginUserGoogle}>LOGIN GOOGLE</button>           
      </div>
    );
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line `this.props.router.push('/prueba')` to `<Redirect to="/prueba" />`.

Comment: I tried with your solution but... i see this error
Error: <Redirect> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered

Comment: @jmrosdev Ah yes, I see now that you're using react-router v3. Shubham's answer (in his second code block) should work for v3. Pretty much what you did except since it's a programmatic redirection and not a rendered component, you should not put it within a return statement (which is what you did in your original code).