# validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `Material-UI` in my project, I'm getting a warning in the console:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>
```

even though there are no direct descendants,

```
<form>
  <TextField
    label="Title"
    value={title}
    onChange={this.handleChange("title")}
    className={classes.formControl}
    margin="normal"
  />
  <br />
  <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel>Muscles</InputLabel>
    <Select
      value={muscles}
      onChange={this.handleChange("muscles")}
    >
      {categories.map((category, index) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key="index" value={category}>
            {category}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
  <br />
  <TextField
    multiline
    rows={4}
    label="Description"
    value={description}
    onChange={this.handleChange("description")}
    className={classes.formControl}
    margin="normal"
  />
</form>
```

Here's the Sandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-0yqeo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [validateDOMNesting warning React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282998/validatedomnesting-warning-react)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default `elementType` for the `Fab` component is [button](https://material-ui.com/api/fab/#props). In your App the `Fab` component is already nested in a `Button` component hence the error. The `Fab` component inherits from `ButtonBase` so you should be able to remove the top level `Button` component and use `onClick` directly on it:

```
<Fab
  color="secondary"
  aria-label="add"
  size="small"
  onClick={this.handleToggle}
>
  <AddIcon />
</Fab>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the button is having one more button as a child then we recive this error, if the parent component is having button property remove the child button