# Going back from a redirect tag - React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, react-redux

Currently, I created a search bar and I have my search bar linked to my search results like this:

```
render() {
if (this.props.itemsFetchSuccess) {
  return (
    <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/search',
      search: `?item-name=${this.props.searchQuery}`
    }} />
  );
```

as part of the render component of my search bar.

GOOGLE CHROME MAIN -> MAIN LANDING -> SEARCH RESULTS.

But I'm suspecting that because I used a redirect tag in React-Router v4, it's not adding it to the browser history stack. If I press back on a browser from the search results page, it won't go back to the page before (i.e. the main landing) but it'll go back to the page before the main landing.

Is there a better way of doing this as I tried using a Link tag as well but that doesn't work since it just generates the link and doesn't actually redirect once the search results are completed.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you well enough, but maybe `window.location.href` will be the answer?

Comment: What I mean is that after I click on the search bar, it makes a redux call to request the data from my api so it loads right when its finished. But because I need the routing to stay the same "pathname, search fields" I'm trying to find another way to do it without the redirect tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` overrides the current entry in `history stack` and hence you are not able to navigate to the current location on history stack.

See its **[documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)**

You could instead programatically navigate using `history.push()` in `componentWillReceiveProps` function.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.itemsFetchSuccess !== this.props.itemsFetchSucess && nextProps.itemsFetchSuccess) {
         this.props.history.push({
              pathname: '/search',
              search: `?item-name=${nextProps.searchQuery}`
         })
    }
}
```

P.S. Make sure that the component in which you are using `history.push` is receiving the Router props, either from the connected component or using `withRouter`. Check this answer for more details on [**how to programmatically navigate using React-router**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108)

Answer (score 7):

In your case you can use Redirect with ***push*** argument. When press back button it will redirect to previous page correctly.

*push: bool

When true, redirecting will push a new entry onto the history instead of replacing the current one.

```
<Redirect push to={{
    pathname: '/search',
    search: `?item-name=${this.props.searchQuery}`
}} />
```

Comment: I have been fighting this issue with React Router for weeks now and this was exactly what I needed to do. It was driving me insane. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.props.history.push(`/search?item-name=${this.props.searchQuery}`);
```