# React native, How to set initial path for react router?

Tags: react-native, react-router

I think the default path being matched is `/` for the react native view.

Is there a way to set the initial path so that react router's `Route` component can match the path?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do, set up /home as the default Route?? or render a component defaultly

Comment: yes I'd like to use something like /home as the default route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use `Redirect` to redirect to the default Route like

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
       <Route path="/home" component={Home}
       <Redirect to="/home"/>
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: I guess it has one downside, that you get two paths in your navigate history instead of just one (`/home`) preferably.

Comment: @eugene, no thats not the case , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956592/going-back-from-a-redirect-tag-react-router/47959652#47959652