# trigger componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router

I am starting with typescript and react redux. I have a login component which in turns has it's action creator which dispatch the LOGIN_SUCCESS action:

```
export const actionCreators = {
    loginRequest: (user:string): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
         userService.login(JSON.parse(user))
         .then(
             (data)=>{//ok
                dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', success: true, message: data });    

            },
            (data)=>{//error
                toast.error(""+data)
            }
        );

        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_REQUEST' });
    },
...
};
```

then on the reducer:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<LoginState> = (state: LoginState, action: KnownAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
            return {... state};
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
            return {... state ,success:action.success, message:action.message};
        case 'LOGIN_FAILURE':
            ...
        default:
            ...
    }

   ...
};
```

I am updating the state. Then I expect that in the component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps: LoginProps){
        console.log(newProps);
        if(newProps.success){
            this.props.history.push('/home')
        }
    }
```

it will receive the new props and push me to /home, but nothing happens. I have setted a `console.log(newProps)` to check when it gets the new properties, but it's never hitted. Can anyone help me? Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

this is how i got them connected:

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.login, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    loginState.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
  )(Login) as typeof Login;
```

Comment: Is your component being connected to your `LoginState`? A prop update will only be triggered if there are actually props to update.

Comment: Is your component connected to the store? (Are you calling [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) from the Redux API?)

Comment: I have edited the question. I am using connect in the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative option would to instead use **react-router-dom** `<Redirect />` to redirect to "/home" when `signup.success` merged into props from the Redux store is `true`/truthy:

```
{this.props.signup && this.props.signup.success &&
    <Redirect to="/home" />
}
```

As your Login component is connected to the Redux store, you can simply listen/watch the mapStateToProps values rather than needing the `Component` life cycle hooks.

If you do utilize this approach, you'd need to likely wrap your connected `Login` component with [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter):

```
export default withRouter(connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => ({signup: state.signup}), 
    loginState.actionCreators
  )(Login)) as typeof Login;
```

Hopefully that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: this line is giving me trouble(state: ApplicationState) => ({signup: state.signup}). When I add ({signup: state.signup}), then ...(Login)) as typeof Login is thowing an error. perhaps I have to add something to the state?

Comment: It must be a compiler error due to TypeScript. I'm not 100% sure how the exported element would need to be typed to avoid the compiler error, but the `<Router />` is an approach can be taken to redirect accordingly based on a conditional property. Without TypeScript it basically looks like `export default withRouter(connect(...)(Login))`

Comment: the editor is complaining about this: Type 'typeof Login' provides no match for the signature '(props: { signup: SignupState; }& { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'

Comment: do I still need mapStateToProps, eve if i did the connect in the way exposed above?

Comment: You are using mapStateToProps in your example, that's just the function that's passed into 1st argument of `connect()`. You are already successfully mapping/merging values into the component props. The argument is referred to as `mapStateToProps` in the react-redux documentation.

Comment: yo know, in the way i was doing it(componentWillReceiveProps did not work, though) I was able to see the success property being set to true in the redux dev tools, but the componentWillReceiveProps did not got triggered

Comment: This may be an issue with the mapStateToProps function. Try logging/inspecting what's returned from `state` within that function where you return `({signup: state.signup})`. Make sure you are retrieving `signup` and returning `signup` effectively. If you are seeing action 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' it could be an issue with what's being returned in that mapStateToProps function.

Comment: Never mind. I did exactly as you said and It worked. After hours banging my head against the wall i discovered i had a typo: I was referring to the signup state, but the state I was really changing was the login. thank you very much for yor time

Comment: Glad to help and glad to hear the issue was resolved! It comes down to what the states of each reducer in something like `combineReducers()` are namespaced as using the passed in keys. Please make sure to mark the answer that assisted in the resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object from the first argument of connect

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => ({signup: state.signup}), // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    loginState.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
  )(Login) as typeof Login;
```

and then use it as

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps: LoginProps){
    console.log(newProps);
    if(newProps.signup.success){
        this.props.history.push('/home')
    }
}
```

assuming the router props are available to the component, if not check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108)**

Comment: I am checking th link you provided. Because this line throws an error: (state: ApplicationState) => {signup: state.signup},

Comment: sorry for the issue check the update, basically we need to wrap `{signup: state.signup}` within `()` to return it

Comment: oh man, sorry for being a pain on the a**, but now it's telling me this:Type 'typeof Login' provides no match for the signature '(props: { signup: SignupState; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.

Comment: can your just remove that part from the code and check

Comment: the error is displaying in this line in the editor: )(Login) as typeof Login;maybe i have to add something to the signup state?