# Rerouting inside a React component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
render() {
 if(this.state.verified){
  return(<div>Verified</div>)
 }else {
   return(<Redirect to='/'/>)
 }
}
```

This is producing an error *< Redirect> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered*

This is how i understood rerouting should be done from react router docs. What is wrong with the code above and how should conditional re-routing done in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error that you are getting, I am assuming that you are using a react-router version < v4. Before version 4, `Redirect` & `Route` components can only be children of `Router` component and can't be nested within the components. In those cases what you would need to do is to programmatically redirect to a different Route

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextState.verified !== this.state.verified && !nextState.verified) { 
       //Programmatically Route here
    }
}
render() {
 if(this.state.verified){
  return(<div>Verified</div>)
 }
}
```

Check this on how to **[Programmatically change routes with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that the component you're calling this method in is not being used inside of a ReactRouter. i.e. if your component is called MyComponent it should be called inside of the application router something like this:

```
const RoutedApp = () => (
  <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/my_component" component={MyComponent} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, root);
```

Comment: My routes.js has `< Route component={App} path='/'>`