# Can't programmatically navigate using react router V4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am currently trying to redirect the user when an article of my website get clicked, however, I am getting the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
onArticleClicked**

> 13 |
>
> 14 | onArticleClicked() {
>
> 15 |     // go to http://my-react-app.com/article/{articleID}
>
> **16 |     this.props.history.push("/article/" + this.article.ID)**
>
> 17 | }
>
> 18 |
>
> 19 | priceToDouble() {

There is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { centimesToDouble } from '../../utils/price_converter';

export default class Article extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            article: props.article
        }
    }

    onArticleClicked() {
        // go to http://my-react-app.com/article/{articleID}
        this.props.history.push("/article/" + this.article.ID)
    }

    priceToDouble() {
        return centimesToDouble(this.state.article.price / 100) + "€"
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.onArticleClicked}>
                <Image src={this.state.article.variants[0].pictureUrl} responsive />
                <h3>{this.state.article.name}</h3>
                <p>{this.priceToDouble()}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't get it because, based on other stackoverflow answers, I should be able to redirect like that, why can't I?

I am trying to learn reactjs through this project, feel free to give any advices, thank you

Comment: put this line in the constructor: `this.onArticleClicked = this. onArticleClicked .bind(this);`

Comment: Also check [Programmatically navigate using React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108) apart from the duplicate

Comment: Ok, I then took a look at both of your comments, thank you ! It seems to work, however **console.log(this.article)** is displaying *undefined* in `onArticleClicked()`

Comment: @Emixam23, this.article is anyways undefined, you have to use `this.state.article`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri So use to develop in C#.... my bad thank you !