# setState of a component before rendering next component React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a button on click of which i am navigating to the other component

```
<Link to="/result"><button onClick = {this.setDealSizeAndType} name="patient">Calculate</button></Link>

  setDealSizeAndType({ target }){

    const dealTypeName = target.name ;
    this.setState({
      dealType: dealTypeName
    }, function(){
        this.props.setDealType(this.state.dealType);
    });
  }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    setDealType: (dealType) =>{
      dispatch(setType(dealType));
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calculator);
```

But the state is not getting set. I am getting undefined. I have to get this value in my next component which is not related to this component. Is there any way , i can set the state , before rendering of next component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a link, you can dynamically navigate

```
<button onClick = {this.setDealSizeAndType} name="patient">Calculate</button>

  setDealSizeAndType({ target }){

    const dealTypeName = target.name ;
    this.setState({
      dealType: dealTypeName
    }, function(){
        this.props.setDealType(this.state.dealType);
        this.props.history.push('/result');  // Programmatically navigate like this
    });
  }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    setDealType: (dealType) =>{
      dispatch(setType(dealType));
    }
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calculator));
```

You can check this answer on [`How to Programmatically navigate using react router`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bind function when calling the onclick handler, so here goes the updated code

```
<Link to="/result"><button onClick = {this.setDealSizeAndType.bind(this,'patient')}>Calculate</button></Link>
```

Now in the function setDealSizeAndType, you will directly receive the name.

```
 setDealSizeAndType(name){

const dealTypeName = name ;
this.setState({
  dealType: dealTypeName
}, function(){
    this.props.setDealType(this.state.dealType);
});
}
```

Hope this helps