# Why in the new react-router-dom <Redirect/> does not fire inside the setTimout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-dom

So, I tried to make a little delay between the logout page and redirecting to the main website page. But I fall into the problem, that the **react-router-dom** `<Redirect/>` method does not want fire when we put it inside the `setTimeout()` of `setInterval()`.

So, if we unwrapped it from timer, the `<Redirect/>` will work normally.

What is the problem is, any suggestions?

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class LogoutPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(e) {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3016/logout')
        .then(
            this.setState({
                navigate: true
            }),
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });

        if (this.state.navigate) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return <Redirect to="/employers" />
            }, 2000);
        }
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.navigate) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                 return <Redirect to="/employers" />
            }, 2000);
        }
        return (
            <div>You successfully logouted</div>
        )
    }
}

export default LogoutPage;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want the `render()` method to return `<Redirect />` in order for the redirect to take place. Currently the `setTimeout` function returns a `<Redirect />`, but this does not affect the outcome of the `render()` itself.

So instead, the `render()` should simply `return <Redirect /`> if `this.state.navigate` is `true` and you delay the `setState({ navigate: true })` method with 2 seconds.

Here's a corrected, declarative way of doing it:

```
class LogoutPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(e) {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3016/logout')
        .then(() => setTimeout(() => this.setState({ navigate: true }), 2000))
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });

    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.navigate) {
          return <Redirect to="/employers" />
        }

        return (
          <div>You successfully logouted</div>
        );
    }
}
```

For the imperative version, see @Shubham Khatri's answer.

Comment: you're on the right track - declarative first is React's philosophy, will be happy if you accept my answer then!:-)

Answer (score 2):

`Redirect` needs to be rendered for it to work, if you want to redirect from an api call, you can use `history.push` to programmatically navigate. Also you would rather use setState callback instead of timeout

```
componentDidMount(e) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3016/logout')
    .then(
        this.setState({
            navigate: true
        }, () => {
            this.props.history.push("/employers");
        }),
    )
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Check [`Programmatically Navigate using react-router`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108) for more details

Even if you add Redirect within setTimeout in render it won't work because it will not render it, rather just be a part of the return in setTimeout

Comment: Thank you, but can we make it work by ComponentDidUpdate/ComponentWllUpdate?

Comment: And also, why just in the `setTimeout` my code does not wont to work? Because it work normally without te timer.

Comment: You can avoid using setTimeout and work using setState callback or componentDidUpdate