# React redirection to another domain based on value of localstorage item

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

My login application (react) and actual (react) application are in the same domain. My login application sets localStorage when user logs in successfully. In my actual application i have to check that value . if it is not there i have to redirect to login application in onload . What is the best practice to do that

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Programmatically Navigate using react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108)

Comment: i can not use mentioned solution because my login and actual application are different.

Comment: In that case you cannot use Router, you need to use window.location

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in the `componentDidMount` life cycle method as below.

```
class LoggedInComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!localStorage.get('loggedIn')) {
      window.location = "/login";
      // You mentioned login app and actual app is deferent.
      // So you should use window.location
      // Otherwise you can use react-router's router.push('/login') function.
    }
  }
}
```

Use `componentDidMount` only. Because `react v17` is going to deprecate the `componentWillMount` function.

Comment: thank you for the response. Can' we do in the router part..? i am just checking. Because i am just thinking about user experience while switching

Comment: No you cannot do it with the router if both applications are different.