# I need to update state in render() function in reactjs. How?

Tags: reactjs

What are the solutions for this problem?

```
<Form.Field>
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <MockMutation mutation={DO_LOGIN}>
    {(doLogin, { loading, error, data }) => {
      if (!loading && data.loggedInState == "LOGGED_IN") {
        // this.setState({goodLogin: true})
        // I need to update state here to redirect to other page
        // How can I do it with out the annoying warning???
      }
      return (
        <Button
          primary
          className="login-btn full-width"
          disabled={loading}
          onClick={e => {
            console.log("on click btn clicked");
            e.preventDefault();
            doLogin({
              variables: {
                employeeId: this.state.employeeId,
                password: this.state.password
              }
            });
          }}
        >
          <span style={loading ? { display: "none" } : {}}>Login</span>
          <span style={loading ? {} : { display: "none" }}>Loading...</span>
        </Button>
      );
    }}
  </MockMutation>
</Form.Field>
```

Comment: you cannot - you need to do it else where try looking at docs for life-cycle methods - specifically component will receive props

Comment: do you use react-router-4 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router.v4 you can use `Redirect` component to do make a redirect.

```
if (!loading && data.loggedInState == "LOGGED_IN") {
  // this.setState({goodLogin: true})
  // I need to update state here to redirect to other page
  // How can I do it with out the annoying warning???
  return <Redirect to="/some/path" />
}
```

If you don't use react-router-4 then it is fairly easy to implement such component anyway:

```
class Redirect extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const { history, to } = this.props;
    history.push(to);
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}

export default withRouter(Redirect);
```

Comment: If at all this question is entirely related with Redirecting, you could have simply marked it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router .

Comment: I rendered a fake component <Switcher switchFuc={this.setLoginState}  /> this works with no warning. I think it is exactly what <Redirect /> does. Thank you!