# react.js redirect to view

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

i want redirect to "/user". i write but this not work.
how to correctly redirect to the right page

```
  onClick = (e) => {

        this.setState({ errorLoad: false});

        getPlayerInfo(this.state.id).then(data => {
          if(data.success == false) {

            this.setState({ errorLoad: true});
            return;
          }
          this.setState({ user: data.player});
          console.log(data);

          <Redirect to="/user"/>
        });
      }
```

My router list. Among them there is a router with the path "/ user"

```
<Route path="/user" render={(props) => <User {...props} user={this.state.user} />}  />
```

UPADATE 
App.js 
The button I click on is in the component `<SearchForm/>`

```
 render() {

        let style = {marginLeft: '20px'};
        return (
          <div>
            <Header source='https://www.shareicon.net/data/2017/02/15/878753_media_512x512.png'/>
            <SearchForm onClick={this.onClick} style={style} onChange={this.onHandle} placeholder="search"/>
             <Centered style={ {marginTop: '50px'} }>
              <BrowserRouter>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Startup} />
                    <Route path="/user" render={(props) => <User {...props} user={this.state.user} />}  />
                  </Switch>
              </BrowserRouter>
             </Centered>

          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: why not just use `location.href='/user'; ?

Comment: @Curious13 because that would cause a full page refresh

Comment: If this is not done, the parameter

Comment: Oh so you want to redirect without refreshing the page?

Comment: Well, yes it's a type of SPA

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Programmatically Navigate using react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this.props.history` to manually redirect:

```
  onClick = (e) => {

        this.setState({ errorLoad: false});

        getPlayerInfo(this.state.id).then(data => {
          if(data.success == false) {

            this.setState({ errorLoad: true});
            return;
          }
          this.setState({ user: data.player});
          console.log(data);

          this.props.history.push('/user');
        });
      }
```

You should be getting `history` as a prop from your `<Router>` component.

**EDIT:**

Okay thank you for the code update. The SearchForm component is not nested under your BrowserRouter, so it is not getting the history prop. Either move that component inside the BrowserRouter or use the withRouter HOC in SearchForm reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Option 1: Move `SearchForm` inside the `BrowserRouter`

```
 render() {

        let style = {marginLeft: '20px'};
        return (
          <div>
            <Header source='https://www.shareicon.net/data/2017/02/15/878753_media_512x512.png'/>
             <Centered style={ {marginTop: '50px'} }>
              <BrowserRouter>
                  <SearchForm onClick={this.onClick} style={style} onChange={this.onHandle} placeholder="search"/>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Startup} />
                    <Route path="/user" render={(props) => <User {...props} user={this.state.user} />}  />
                  </Switch>
              </BrowserRouter>
             </Centered>

          </div>
        );
      }
```

Option 2: use the `withRouter` HOC to inject the `history` prop into `SearchForm` manually:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class SearchForm extends React.Component { ... }

export default withRouter(SearchForm)
```

Comment: @Санитариум You need to make sure you are passing the props from the `Route` all the way down to the component you are trying to redirect from. If you post more code that would help.

Comment: Or you can use the `withRouter` HOC https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: @Санитариум Okay yes, the `SearchForm` component is not nested under your `BrowserRouter`, so it is not getting the `history` prop. Either move that component inside the `BrowserRouter` or use the `withRouter` HOC in `SearchForm` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to programmatically navigate with React Router - `<Redirect />` and `history.push`. Which you use is mostly up to you and your specific use case.

`<Redirect />` should be used in `user event -> state change -> re-render` order.
The downsides to this approach is that you need to create a new property on the component’s state in order to know when to render the Redirect. That’s valid, but again, that’s pretty much the whole point of React - state changes update the UI.

The real work horse of React Router is the `History` library. Under the hood it’s what’s keeping track of session history for React Router. When a component is rendered by React Router, that component is passed three different props: `location`, `match`, and `history`. This `history` prop comes from the `History` library and has a ton of fancy properties on it related to routing. In this case, the one we’re interested is `history.push`. What it does is it pushes a new entry onto the history stack - aka redirecting the user to another route.

Comment: As @Chase DeAnda mentioned, Your component is not under `Router`. Hence you need to wrap it with `withRouter` which passes `history` props to the component.