# ReactJS Context API - Redirect/Navigate programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router

index.js - file

```
<AppProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/balances" component={Balances} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
</AppProvider>
```

On Home Component, I have a button and its event click was send to App Provider successfully.

```
   <button className="btn btn-primary">{context.Process_ToBalances}</button>
```

And on AppProvider, I have a method like this.

```
Process_ToBalances()
{
   //pre process data
   // Redirect to Balance page here
}
```

ButI have no idea why all the redirection method failed.

I tried both of `browserHistory.push('/Balances')` and `this.props.push("/Balances")` but still failed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: this should help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use react-router functionality in AppProvider, your Router must wrap you AppProvider component and you AppProvider must receive the Router Props, you can do so like

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <AppProvider>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/balances" component={Balances} />
        </div>
    </AppProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and then in AppProvider use withRouter

```
export default withRouter(AppProvider);
```

After this you can use `this.props.history.push('/balances)`, note the case sensitive pathname `/balances` and not `/Balances`

Refer this question for more details on [`How to Programmatically navigate using react-router`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108)

Comment: When I read your comment, I found my mistake. Just move the AppProvider inside BrowserRouter and it can use BrowserRouter props.

Thank you, you made my day