# TypeError: _this2.handleClick is not a function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and creating a login page using React JS and laravel API. When I click the login button after inserting the email address and password it says the above error.

**This is my code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


class Login extends Component
{
  onClick(event)
  {
    var self = this;
    var payload={
      "email":this.state.email,
      "password":this.state.password
    }
  //"role":this.state.loginRole

    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', payload)
    .then(function (response)
    {
      console.log(response);
      if(response.data.code == 200)
      {
        //Set localstorage:
        const userDetails = {userName: this.state.email}
        localStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(userDetails));

        console.log("Login successfull");
        return <Redirect to='/Master'  />

        var uploadScreen=[];
        //  uploadScreen.push(<UploadPage appContext={self.props.appContext} role={self.state.loginRole}/>)
        self.props.appContext.setState({loginPage:[],uploadScreen:uploadScreen})
      }
      else if(response.data.code == 204)
      {
        console.log("Username password do not match");
        alert(response.data.success)
      }

      else
      {
        console.log("Username does not exists");
        alert("Username does not exist");
      }
    })

    .catch(function (error)
    {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
  render()
  {
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="8">
              <CardGroup>
                <Card className="p-4">
                  <CardBody>
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <p className="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="icon-user" />
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="icon-lock" />
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs="6">
                        <Button color="primary" className="px-4" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>
                          Login
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                      <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                        <Button color="link" className="px-0">
                          Forgot password?
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
                <Card
                  className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none"
                  style={{ width: 44 + "%" }}
                >
                  <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Sign up</h2>
                      <p>
                        Are you a new user to the Restaurant system? Hooray now , you can create an account...
                      </p>
                      <Button color="primary" className="mt-3" active>
                        Register Now!
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </CardGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

In this case I gave the following as the payload

```
Username : admin@admin.com
Password : 123456
```

the above credentials are valid in Laravel API. What wrong in this code to get error as `TypeError: _this2.handleClick is not a function`?

Comment: Where's your handleclick function? Cant see it in the code. And also ... _this2 ... where is that? Can't find it either

Answer (score 2):

Your function is defined to be `onClick` and not `handleClick`, Also if only you need to call a function with the default parameters such as event, you don't need to make use of arrow function, you can simply write

```
onClick={this.onClick}
```

and bind it in `constructor` or define it as a class property with arrow function

```
onClick = (event) => {}
```

or

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}
```

Also `Redirect` is supposed to be rendered but it can't be rendered from within the axios request or onClick handler. Instead you can make use of `this.props.history.push` to redirect. Check [Programmatically Navigate using react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108) question for more details

Comment: I think the `onClick` function needs to be bind with the constructor as well.

Comment: @PranayTripathi True, of defined as an arrow function

Comment: @Lennholm I updated my answer to take that into consideration

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, thank you. but it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`and highlights this line `"email":this.state.email,`

Comment: @testteam, did you bind you onClick function as mentioned in the answer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, yeah, as you said, I add `onClick={this.onClick} 
` and `constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}` but when I entered the email and passsword, it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null`

Comment: the axios .then function is not bound. use it with an arrow function like

`axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', payload)
    .then((response) => {}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to name `onClick`    to   `handleClick`

Comment: if I change to `handleClick`, after that click not works.

Comment: You've got  `onClick(event)` a few lines after the class definition, change that to `handleClick(event)`, not the `onClick` event on the button. You want to have the `onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}` untouched!