# Adding the sub Route in the react js React router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am new to the react router. what I have is ,

**Main.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          {this.props.isFetching && <Loading />}
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/create-job" component={NewJob} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, In this, I have the route which is `create-job` . Now, In this there is one container `NewJob.js`

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <SubHeader isAuthenticated={localStorage.getItem("access_token") ? true : false} />
        <JobNotFound />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
```

Now, In the `JObNotFound.js` there is a button which is like ,

```
<div className="col-sm-4">
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block button-container">Create New Job</button>
            </div>
```

Now, Here what I want to do is , `onclick of this button`, I want to change route to the `create-job/New` and want to render a new component over there.

So,I am totally confused in this place. Can any one help me with this ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`Link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108) component from react-router of [`Programmatically navigate onClick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108) of the button component

```
  import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

  ...


  <div className="col-sm-4">
        <Link to="create-job"><button type='button' className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block button-container">Create New Job</button></Link>
  </div>
```

Comment: So, I just have to use this with to=create-job/new and then in main component, <PrivateRoute exact path="/create-job/new" component={createnew} />

Comment: Yes, Also make sure JobNotFound page is rendered with  `<Route component={JobNotFound} />` so that it receives Router props and Link works correctly or else you can export JobNotFound like `export default withRouter(JobNotFound)` where withRouter is imported from react-router-dom

Comment: Okay so I will just add withRouter in the JobNotFound page

Comment: Because I am confused where should I use that <Route component ={JobNotFound} />

Comment: Where you are rendering `<JobNotFound />`

Comment: I have added that in question it is in the NewJob.js which renders on /create-job

Comment: Okay so here on click of that button I have used your code and then it redirected user to the new page with the

Answer (score 0):

In JobNotFound.js, import withRouter, and then wrap the component

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
...
//at the bottom
export default withRouter(JobNotFound)
```

Then in bind onClick button like following:

```
<div className="col-sm-4">
    <button onClick={()=>{this.props.history.push(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/create-job/New`)}} className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block button-container">Create New Job</button>
 </div>
```