# ReactJS Router V4 history.push not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have upgraded to React Router V4 and now struggling with the `history.push` method.

I have an index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

import { Main} from "./components/Main";
import { About } from "./components/About";
import { Cars} from "./components/Cars";


class App extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>

            <div>
                <Route path={"/"} component={Main} />
                <Route path={"/cars"} component={Cars}/>
                <Route path={"/about"} component={About}/>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

And then I have another file, where I added a simple to return to a certain page which looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export class Cars extends React.Component {
  navigateBack() {
    history.push('/')
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h3>Overview of Cars</h3>
            <p>Model: </p>
            <button onClick={this.navigateBack} className="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So, I cannot figure out whats going wrong here. When I click on the button, the URL changes to `/` but thats all. Is there someone who can help me out?

**EDIT**

I found out, that it works when I do this:

```
this.props.history.push('/home')
```

and

```
<button onClick={this.onNavigateHome.bind(this)}
```

but it seems wrong somehow??

when I do

```
this.context.history.push('/home')
```

I get `Cannot read property 'context' of null` but why?? Is my `<BrowserRouter>` setup wrong??

Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: BrowserRouter has an implicit history by default. You'd need to use Router instead.

Reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: For React Router V4 you can this.context.router.history.push('/url');

Answer (score 17):

You have to import `{withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'` and export your class in this way

`export default withRouter(Cars)`

Comment: The hoc `withRouter` was imported from `react-router` not `react-router-dom`.  Check [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) for more information.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding forceRefresh={true} to your BrowserRouter.

```
<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>
```

Comment: This probably isn't a good approach, but not sure why.

Comment: Worked for me, @Android why do you think so ?

Answer (score 1):

With v4 you have to use `this.context.history.push('/cart');`

check out these posts for more insights:

[How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

[history.push not working when using BrowserRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059)

Comment: Strange - that didn't work, even though my research gave me the same answer. I have found a solution but it seems wrong sowmehow. I have edited my post so make it clear. Maybe you know the explanation?

Comment: I work with v4 and I don't have `this.context.history`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use history from props and ensure that your export is wrapped with withRouter.

Ex:

```
this.props.history.push('/test')


export default withRouter(TestComponent)
```