# Go to a page on another file in React Navigation (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two files. App.js and newPage.js. I'm trying to get to a page on newPage.js from App.js. I'm completely new to React native so I'm having a bit of trouble getting this to work.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, FlatList, View, Button, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import NewPage from './src/newPage';

export default class App extends React.Component {
   navigateToNew = () => {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('NewPage');
   }
   render() {
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
     return (
      <View>
         <Text>Home Screen</Text>
         <Button
            title="New Page"
            onPress={ this.navigateToNew }
         />
      </View>
   );
 }
}
```

newPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 

export default class NewPage extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <View>
            <Text>New Screen</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
 }
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any help would be awesome!

EDIT: I am using React Navigation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118263/redirect-using-react-router)

Comment: Unless i'm missing something. I'm pretty sure im using React Navigation instead of react router. If react router could achieve the same result in React Native i would be open to check it out however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the alternatives you can go first.

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    newscreen: newPage
  },
});
```

and return RootStack in App class. 
The code that provides navigation is

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ComponentName')
```

If you run this code with onClick, the navigation process happens. But dont forget, RootStack must be created.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe i made such a mistake! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

App.js

> import React from 'react'; import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
>   import {createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; import
>   SafeAreaView from 'react-native-safe-area-view'; import {
>   createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'; import ThankPage
>   from './ThankPage';
>
> const RootStack = createStackNavigator({   Home: {
>       Home: HomeScreen,
>       Thank: ThankPage   }, });
>
> ```
>  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
>  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
>  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
>
>   class HomeScreen extends React.Component {   navigateToNew = () => {
> this.props.navigation.navigate('ThankPage'); }  render() {
>  const onbtnPress = () =>{
> alert("Thank you")  }
> return (
> <SafeAreaView>
> <View style={styles.container}>
>
>   <Image
>   source = {require('./login_img.png')}
>   style = {{ width: 350, height: 150 }} />
>
>       <ImageBackground style={styles.imgback}
>         source = {require('./login_back.png')}
>         style = {{ width: 340, height: 250 }}>
>
>           <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
>           <TextInput
>             style={{ height: 20,borderColor: 'gray' }}
>             value={username}
>             onChangeText={username =>setUsername(username)}
>             placeholder={"Username"}
>             underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
>             />
>             </View>
>             <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
>           <TextInput
>             style={{ height: 20,borderColor: 'gray' }}
>             onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}
>             value={password}
>             placeholder={"Password"}
>             underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
>             secureTextEntry={true}
>             inlineImageLeft="./eye_close_icon.imageset/eye_close_icon.png"
>             />
>             <Image source={require('./eye_close_icon.imageset/eye_close_icon.png')}
> ```
>
> style={styles.ImageStyle} />
>
> ```
>    <TouchableOpacity 
>
>    onPress={ this.navigateToNew }
>    >
>       <Image source={require('./btn_back.png')} style={styles.imgbtnok} />
>       <Text style={styles.white }>Submit & SYNC</Text>
>     </TouchableOpacity>
>
> </View>
> </SafeAreaView>   ); }   }
> ```
>
> const styles = StyleSheet.create({   container: {
>       flex: 1,
>       backgroundColor: 'grey',
>       alignItems: 'center',
>       justifyContent: 'center',
>       margin:10,   },   SectionStyle: {
>       flexDirection: 'row',
>       justifyContent: 'center',
>       alignItems: 'center',
>       backgroundColor: '#fff',
>       borderWidth: .5,
>       borderColor: '#000',
>       height: 40,
>       borderRadius: 5 ,
>       margin: 25   },   imgback: {
>       opacity:1,   },   ImageStyle: {
>       height: 25,
>       width: 25,
>       resizeMode : 'stretch',   },   white: {
>       // Define your HEX color code here.
>       color: '#FFFFFF',
>       marginLeft:135,
>       marginTop:-55,   },   imgbtnok: {
>       height: 80,
>       width: 130,
>       marginLeft: 120,
>       position: 'relative',
>       resizeMode : 'stretch',   }, });
>
> export default class App extends React.Component {
>
> render() {
>       return ;   } }

I tried to understand a lot but getting errors.[myError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz9Th.jpg)