# TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to redirect the user to the login page when the /logout routes is hit. The auth is working (jwt token is removed, but the app fails to redirect to /login.

Also If I do to / the app crashes as well.

On the Login route I uses withRouter from the react-router-dom package wih this I can access the `this.props.history.push('/redirect_to_a_new_path')`, but when I try to wrap the App component with `withRouter` method it crashes as well.

Please help!

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/isaklafleur/adventurespots/tree/dev):

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import lightBaseTheme from "material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme";
import getMuiTheme from "material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme";
import injectTapEventPlugin from "react-tap-event-plugin";

// Components
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import SpotMap from "./components/SpotMap";
import SignUpPage from "./components/containers/SignUpPage";
import LoginPage from "./components/containers/LoginPage";
import DashboardPage from "./components/containers/DashBoardPage";
import NotFound from "./components/NoteFound";
import Auth from "./modules/Auth";
import "./styles/App.css";

injectTapEventPlugin();

const handleLogout = event => {
  Auth.deauthenticateUser();
  this.props.history.push("/login");
};

const isLoggedIn = event => {
  if (Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) {
    this.props.history.push(DashboardPage);
  } else {
    this.props.history.push(HomePage);
  }
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={isLoggedIn} />
              <Route path="/spotmap" component={SpotMap} />
              <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
              <Route path="/signup" component={SignUpPage} />
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
              <Route path="/logout" component={handleLogout} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is written in React Router v3 and this is what I need to convert to React Router V4. **The routes that does not work for me are the "/" and "logout" routes.**

```
import Base from './components/Base.jsx';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.jsx';
import DashboardPage from './containers/DashboardPage.jsx';
import LoginPage from './containers/LoginPage.jsx';
import SignUpPage from './containers/SignUpPage.jsx';
import Auth from './modules/Auth';


const routes = {
  // base component (wrapper for the whole application).
  component: Base,
  childRoutes: [

    {
      path: '/',
      getComponent: (location, callback) => {
        if (Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) {
          callback(null, DashboardPage);
        } else {
          callback(null, HomePage);
        }
      }
    },

    {
      path: '/login',
      component: LoginPage
    },

    {
      path: '/signup',
      component: SignUpPage
    },

    {
      path: '/logout',
      onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
        Auth.deauthenticateUser();

        // change the current URL to /
        replace('/');
      }
    }

  ]
};

export default routes;
```

Comment: could you include the _error_?

Comment: Hello @edgaromar90! The error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined". I get this because, I have not included withRouter from the react-router-dom package, but I do not know how to include it here in the App module with the routes there..

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
isLoggedIn
src/App.js:35
  32 |   if (Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) {
  33 |     this.props.history.push(DashboardPage);
  34 |   } else {
> 35 |     this.props.history.push(HomePage);
  36 |   }
  37 | };
  38 |

Comment: Can you try this? `<Route exact path="/" render={() => {if (Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) { (<DashboardPage)/>)} else {(<HomePage/>)}}} />`

Comment: That solved the / route error! Can you please have how I can solve the redirect to /login after logging out? Thanks!!

Comment: sure! I'll add it to the Answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use useHistory.

Do:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Instead of:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
```

(Or else the same error message will appear.)

Answer (score 5):

For the `/` route you should use **render** like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {
  if (Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) { 
    (<DashboardPage)/>)
  } else {
    (<HomePage/>)
  }
}} />
```

For your `/logout` route using `<Redirect>`

```
<Route path="/logout" render={() => {
    Auth.deauthenticateUser();
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />;
    }}
/>
```

Comment: If there's still a problem let me know here so I can help you.

Comment: Hi @edgaromar90! I added the code for the /logout path:               <Route
                path="/logout"
                render={history => {
                  Auth.deauthenticateUser() && history.push("/");
                }}
              />
I get this error:
Route.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: In this answer they are using withRouter method. Something I can use? Please let me know if you can help we solve the logout path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4

Comment: Fixed it using `redirect` @IsakLaFleur

Comment: Thank you @edgaromar90! I also posted an alternative solution i just tried using withRouter. I gave you the best answer as you was so helpful!!

Answer (score 3):

I post a second solution for the /logout path using **withRouter** and **this.props.history.push('/login')**.

1. Point the /logout Route to its own component "Logout"
2. wrap the Logout component with withRouter method from react-router-dom.

**Logout.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Auth from "../modules/Auth";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Logout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
  }
  handleLogout() {
    Auth.deauthenticateUser();
    this.props.history.push("/login");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.handleLogout()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Logout);
```