# how to use react-router Link with semantic-ui Menu.Item?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui

I have this:

```
  <Link to="/">
    <Menu.Item name='expense List' active={activeItem === 'expense List'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
  </Link>
```

but I get an error in the console:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
    in a (created by MenuItem)
    in MenuItem (at Header.js:26)
    in a (created by Link)
    in Link (at Header.js:25)
    in div (created by Menu)
    in Menu (at Header.js:22)
    in div (at Header.js:20)
    in Header (at AddExpense.js:8)
    in div (at AddExpense.js:7)
    in AddExpense (created by Route)
    in Route (at index.js:20)
    in Switch (at index.js:18)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:17)
    in Routes (at index.js:30)
```

How should I properly define my links?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's an `onClick props` for each `Menu.Item` in Material UI. You can use `this.props.history.push('/')` inside the onClick handler:

```
<Menu.Item
  name='expense List'
  active={activeItem === 'expense List'}
  onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/')} />
  // You can also define the function outside and call history.push there
```

You might want to use `withRouter` though. See [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 11):

You can just use `as` prop in SemanticUI components.

```
...
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";

...
<Menu.Menu>
   <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/path">Click me</Menu.Item>
</Menu.Menu>
...
```

Comment: This is the best answer — the official documentation recommends the same technique of  using `as` for `react-router`: https://react.semantic-ui.com/#augmentation