# React: Stop page reload on clicking on anchor tag for scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I am currently using react to create a Wikipedia style website. For data entry reasons, I am fetching an entire HTML from the database and then using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to set some part of it, like so:

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.section.text }}
```

Now there are other parts of the page that have a video playing in it, however every time I click on an `<a href="#id>` style tag (set using the database) to navigate to another part of the same page, the entire page refreshes.

This creates a problem since the video reloads as well and starts playing from the beginning.

Is there any way to use a dangerously set anchor tag to scroll to parts of a page in React without full page reload?

Edit: Using following versions:

> "react": "^16.0.0", "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: @Chris I am using react-router@4.2.2

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is to add an eventListener to your component which listens to all anchor tags whose `href` attribute value start with `#`.

Inside your `componentDidMount()` method, select all your `<a>` tags where `href="#..."`. You can do this with `document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']")`. That will return an array of all nodes that were matched. You can then loop through them and attach an eventListener to each one.

The eventListener would listen to `click` and run a function which prevents the default behavior (redirect to another page) and instead push to your router. (Remove the comment below)

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']").forEach(node => {
      node.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.href);
        //this.props.history.push(e.target.href);
      });
    })
  }
 
  render() {
    const myMarkup = "<ul><li><a href='#'>Page link 1</a></li><li><a href='#test'>Page link 2</a></li><li><a href='https://google.com'>External link</a></li></ul>";
    return(
      <div id="container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: myMarkup}}></div>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The above snippet assumes you are using the `withRouter` HOC. Otherwise the push won't work. For more info, see my answer to [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/2030321).

Comment: This still does not solve my problem :( The video is also fetched from the db and it still restarts every time I click the anchor tag, and I can see a database fetch in the console on every click as well (which is ultimately what I am trying to prevent). Is there anyway to not trigger the redux action on scroll?

Answer (score 1):

catch default eventhandler and handle event handling yourself. you can put this in componentDidMount lifecycle hook. Also remove these handlers in componentWillUnmount

```
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]'); //use apt selector for you section


     aTags.forEach(aTag =>aTag.addEventListener('click',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()
          e.stopPropagation()
          var href = e.target.href;
          history.pushState({},'',href);
        }));
```

Comment: Using a Jquery selector to attach event listeners to DOM or modify it in any way? This defeats the whole purpose of using React.

Comment: @ShishirArora The updated version is again wrong, since React is using Synthetic events.

Comment: all synthetic events are handled at document object. We can use this

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and while I share the concerns of the other commenters, I have to also add that is not really stopping the reload behaviour. Any other ways out there?

Comment: @KehkashanFazal try now. Corrected syntax

Comment: The same thing I told @Chris: This still does not solve my problem :( The video is also fetched from the db and it still restarts every time I click the anchor tag, and I can see a database fetch in the console on every click as well (which is ultimately what I am trying to prevent). Is there anyway to not trigger the redux action on scroll?

Comment: use stopImmediatePropagation and stopPropagation also on click,scroll or whatever other events

Answer (score 0):

To add onto what @Shishir Arora was saying, instead of using `history.pushState({},'',href);` use something like `document.getElementById(hash.replace('#', '')).scrollIntoView();`.

Here's code for a full component where I leverage jQuery:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

const handleAnchorClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  const hash = e.currentTarget.hash;
  document.getElementById(hash.replace('#', '')).scrollIntoView();
  // Alternatively use jQuery for the above line: $(hash).get(0).scrollIntoView();
};

export default ({ response, url, search }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    $('#article-content').on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', handleAnchorClick);

    return () => {
      $('#article-content').off('click', 'a[href^="#"]', handleAnchorClick);
    };
  }, [response]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id='article-content' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: response}} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

jQuery was helpful in capturing the `currentTarget` which won't get captured the same way with @Shishir's original answer because of an element nested within the  tag.

Answer (score -1):

Since your question has the tag "react-router" I assume you use it in your application, I also assume you are using the latest version which v4.x.

The way I have tackled this in the past was using [React Router Hash link](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link) package. As is noted in their documentation, you can use it like that (replace your `<a href="#id">` with `<Link>`):

```
// In YourComponent.js
...
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
...
// Use it just like a RRv4 link (to can be a string or an object, see RRv4 api for details):
<Link to="/some/path#with-hash-fragment">Link to Hash Fragment</Link>
```

Comment: This still causes a re-render

Answer (score -2):

Since you're using React Router v4, why don't you use `Link`?

```
...
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
... 
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/courses',
  search: '?sort=name',
  hash: '#the-hash',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}}/>
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object).

Comment: This still causes a re-render