# Redux dispatch and change URL

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have an following app:

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore(rootReducers, applyMiddleware(createLogger()));

store.dispatch(fetchArticles());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={ArticlesPage}/>
                <Route path='/search' component={SearchPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**ArticlesPage.js**

```
const ArticlesPage = ({groups, onSearch}) => (
    <Grid>
        <SearchBoxWithImages onSearch={onSearch}/>
        <CategorySections groups={groups}/>
    </Grid>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    groups: state.articles.groups
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSearch: (q) => dispatch(searchArticles(q))
});

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ArticlesPage));
```

`fetchArticles` and `searchArticles` are an redux actions.

I wanna handle that case:

- enter site (url `/`)
- after search, handled by a `SearchBoxWithImages` component, I wanna change an url into `/search?q=term` (term is a callback from the `onSearch` handler)
- call action `searchArticles` to set redux state

Currently only state was changed (because of call the `searchArticles` action). Url isn't change, therefore `SearchPage` container wasn't call.

Comment: Can't you use history.push in your searchArticles action creator? Or you are using but url is not changing and this is the problem?

Comment: I didn't use any history.push methods, because of I don't know how I can do it in the best way. Before using a redux I get router from context, and manage state on my own way, but now I wanna use redux to manage app state.

Comment: Look at this question and answers given: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4/42716055 There are lots of good information. Also, there is an alternative way to change navigation with React Router Redirect: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 1):

Create a history object like so

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createBrowserHistory({});
```

Apply it to your router

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../services/history';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={history}>
                    {mainSwitch}
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Wherever you want to programmatically change the route do the following

```
import history from '/path/to/history'

history.push('/path/you/want/to/go/to')
```

This can also be called within your `redux` action so u can call `history.push` after your action has ended.

Comment: Thanks! Are you think a redux action is the best place to call history manager and push news url? And extra question: is there any way to don't use a third party libs, do it using only a react and redux?

Comment: It would be difficult or very messy to do so in your case. However, you can render different component based on state change like in `private route` example in `react router` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it were helpful thanks.

Comment: I found a better pattern using react-router. I can inject into `mapDispatchToProps` history object and use it in the action.