# React Router - this.history.push changes URL but does not show component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

I have a router

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div>
    <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
    <Route exact path='/' component={UserForm} history={history} />
    <Route exact path='/test' component={Test} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

So when I trigger **this.props.history.push('/test');** I expect to see my test component, however the url changes and I see still see the App and UserFrom **until I hit refresh** on the Browser, then it behaves as expected.

I am calling **this.props.history.push('/test');** (on the UserForm component) which does get called as the URL changes.

I have seen people doing **this.context.history.push('/test');** in v4 but I have an empty context

**Edit**

So I tried wrapping it withRouter() as the other answer suggested at all levels with no luck.

```
export default withRouter(Main);
```

However I did notice is does run on render() but not onClick.

```
getUsers = () => {

}
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849608/1482431

Comment: If the url changes maybe your parent component doesn't react to these changes. You may need to check them with *componentDidUpdate*