# How to use history library and <Link> in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, history.js

I'm a beginner with React-Redux, and I had a question of how to use history and the Link tag in order to push to a certain location.

I wanted to be able to use history.push in my actions, so I used the [history JS library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history). I created a history.js file in my app folder:

src/history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

I then imported the history object into my App.js, and had my routes placed within a Router tag with history:

src/App.js

```
<Router history={history}>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/loginscreen" component={Loginscreen} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018/profile" component={Profile} />
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018/properties" component={Property} />
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018/detail/:id" render={(props)=><PropertyDetail{...props}/>} />
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018/new_property" component={NewProperty} />
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018/contact" component={Message} />
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018/edit_property/:id" render={(props)=><EditProperty{...props}/>}/>
        <Route path="/Property-Assistant-2018" component={Initial} />

      </Switch>
```

However, now my Link tags in my nav bar do not work. When I click on them, they just stay at the inital homepage. I tried adding a second set of Switch routes, to see if I can hardcode it and figure out what was going on, but that made the homepage appear stacked on top of the Link route page.

src/App.js

```
<Link to="/Property-Assistant-2018/contact">Contact</Link>
```

So my question is, how can I use history and Link tags at the same time? I know history is included with React-Router v.4, and I've been using this, but I can't use it for my actions.

It's probably a simple fix, so thank you for helping me with this issue.

Comment: Did you add something like `var history = createBrowserHistory();` before you started using history?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue:

I have to wrap the entire App div with the Router tag.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div className="App">
  </div>
</Router>
```

This is part of an answer from this StackOverflow question:
[How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0):

can you show the code

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('moved')
}, [history]);
```

i have this for every url change but with the <Link to={"/somethign"}/> dont work
, but when i console log useHistory every second is diferent and useEffect dont detect the change