# Wait for clicking until the element is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The situation is as follows: I have a `Navigation`, and `Login` components. `Login` is only an exported function, which logs the user in. It's this:

```
export function login() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
                document.getElementById('close').click();
                document.getElementById('questions').click();
            }
        ).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

This works almost perfectly.

This is my `Navigation` component

```
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navbar>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <Link id='home' to="/">UczIchApp</Link>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Nav>
                        <LinkContainer id='about' to='/about'>
                            <NavItem>O nas</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        {// The issue starts here
                            this.state.user ?
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <LinkContainer id="questions" to='/questions'>
                                        <NavItem>Zadania</NavItem>
                                    </LinkContainer>
                                    <NavItem onClick={logout.bind(this)}>Wyloguj się</NavItem>
                                </React.Fragment>
                                :
                                <NavItem onClick={this.openLogin}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
                        }
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutComponent}/>
                    <Route exact path="/questions" component={QuestionsComponent}/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent}/>
                    <Route path='/question/:id' component={QuestionComponent}/>
                </Switch>
                <ModalComponent show={this.state.show} changeShowState={this.changeShowState}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

So when I log the user in, I want him to be transferred to the `Questions` route. I'm trying to do it with click. But the problem is, the `Questions` link is not rendered yet, so I'm getting the: `TypeError: "document.getElementById(...) is null"` error.

How can I make it wait until the component is rendered?

Comment: Why do you access the DOM nodes in your logic function? Please checkout [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50738496/4312466), how to do it in the React way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect a user [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router). There are a few ways to do that, for instance:

If your `Login` component extends `React.Component` you have an access to `history` object like:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
   // use `this.props.history.push('/some/path')` here
};
```

So you can pass `this.props.history` to your `login` function and call `push` when you're logged in:

```
export function login(history) {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
                history.push('/questions');
            }
        ).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: I'm a little lost. How do I initiate the history object?

Comment: You don't have to if you have `extend React.Component`. Just use it as it is. This is works like this since React Router v4, ensure you have it. Read link I provided as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router because there are other options to make redirect from code, one of them for sure will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**It's a really bad idea to access the DOM nodes in the way you're doing it.**

The (React) flow you should follow, has to be:

1. The user enters his credentials (let's say you have `LoginForm` component).
2. Submits the form.
3. On submit, you have a callback that will call your `login` function and pass the credentials as parameters (without coupling the login function with the DOM nodes).
4. If everything is fine redirect the user to the desired route, using the `react-router` API. Something like `login(credentials).then(() => history.push('/questions'))`. Here you can read more about [how to programmatically do the redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/4312466).

**Pseudo code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
   constructor (super) {
     this.state = {
       email: null,
       password: null
     }

     this.login = this.login.bind(this)
   }


  login() {
    const { email, password } = this.state

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => this.props.history.push('/questions'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }

   render() {
     <form onSubmit={this.login}>
      // Controlled inputs
      <input name='email' />
      <input name='password' />

      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
     </form>
   }
}

// Please checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/4312466
export default withRouter(LoginForm)
```

I'll recommend you to take a closer look to the [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting "user" property in state?
Maybe try to use there "history.push" from react-router if user is logged.

Comment: Firebase takes care of the user state for me.