# Component does not render when url loads in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to render a modal component in a particular route, and display certain information in the modal by passing props, I also want to display the page from where the modal is opened as a background and the modal on top.

I am able to change the route but the component does not render.

How do I go about this? I had also split my routes based on different layouts in my app.js file.

App.js

```
 render() {  
   let layoutAssignments = {
      '/': WithLayout,
      '/admin/profiles': WithLayout,
      '/admin/profiles/new': WithLayout,
      '/profiles':WithLayout,
      '/admin/mgmt':WithLayout,
      '/login': WithoutLayout,
      '/donate':WithoutLayout,
      '/admin/profiles/:id':WithoutLayout
    }

    let layoutPicker = function(props){
      var Layout = layoutAssignments[props.location.pathname];
      return Layout ? <Layout/> : <pre>Error 404, Page Not Found</pre>;
    };
    return (
    <Router>
      <Route path = "*" render={layoutPicker} />
    </Router>
    );
  }
  }
```

WithLayout.js

```
class WithLayout extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <> 
                <LayoutContainer>
                    <Switch>
                    {withLayoutRoutes.map(route =><Route key={route.path} path = {route.path} component={route.component}/>)}
                    </Switch>
                </LayoutContainer>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

withRoutes

```
export const withLayoutRoutes = [
    {
        path: path.profilesListing,
        component: ProfilesContainer,
    },
    {
        path: path.profileCreation,
        component: RegistrationContainer,
    },
    {
        path: path.adminProfilesListing,
        component:ProfilesContainer,
    },
    {
        path:path.mgmt,
        component: AdminMgmt,
    }

]
```

Place where i define the routes for the modal i want to open up

```
<Route path={routes.modal + `/:id`} render={(props) => 
  <PlayerDetailsModal {...props} matchTableData= 
    {this.props.modalInfo.matches}
       modalActions = {this.props.modalActions}
       cardActions = {this.props.cardActions}
       modalInfo = {this.props.modalInfo}
       getModificationData={this.props.getModificationData}
       getPlayerDeleteId={this.props.getPlayerDeleteId}
       hoverIdHandler = {this.props.hoverIdHandler}
       hoverId = {this.props.hoverId}
 />
```

I tried to implement withRouter to check for update blocking, but the problem exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, the issue was because of an extra  declaration in the app.js file. Take note to use  from "react-router" than  from "react-router-dom". I had used used Two Routers one in index.js above app.js and one in app.js, which was the main cause of the issue.

[How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4/42716055)