# How to redirect to another component on a button click?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How to redirect a component based on a selected drop down value and button click in react using react router dom ?

I have tried using Redirect tag but i am unable to redirect to another component

Comment: Using history, here is a detailed answer with react router v4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849608/11135550

Comment: Please suggest an example using React router dom v4 using Redirect tag

Answer (score 2):

Link component from react-router can be used for this:

```
<Link to="/other-components-url">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</Link>
```

Any UI element can be nested in "Link" component which when clicked will redirect to specified URL/Component.

For more details visit:
https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Comment: Just the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use props inside your onchange function to go to another page.

```
this.props.history.push('/my-other-components-url');
```

Comment: But where and how is this history declared and passed?

Comment: @dfrankow you can use `withRouter` and access `history` prop. Here's the documentation from their official website https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; 
import { useParams } from "react-router"; 
export const Parent component ()=>{

return(
  <Link to={"/child" + 12 + " "} >
  <Button className="btn btn-icon btn-round  " >  Redirect   </Button>
    </Link>
)
}

 
 
export const Child component ()=>{
 
 let { id} = useParams();
return(
  <div>hello danish your id is : {id}</div>
)
}
```