# How to write redirection inside the axios interceptors without reloading in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, interceptor

I used axios interceptors to maintain the internal server errors. I need to redirect to another url if the response have an error without reloading. Below code I used location.href. So it's reloading. I need a solution to redirect without refreshing the page.

I tried "Redirect" in react-router-dom. But it not works for me.

```
export function getAxiosInstance() {
    const instance = axios.create();
    const token    = getJwtToken();

    // Set the request authentication header
    instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;

    // Set intercepters for response
    instance.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => response,
        (error) => {
            if (config.statusCode.errorCodes.includes(error.response.status)) {
                return window.location.href = '/internal-server-error';
            }

            return window.location.href = '/login';
        }
    );

    return instance;
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this out?

Comment: are you using Redux ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Yes, I am.

Comment: Ok you can import your store instance and dispatch an action that will change route in this case. Or you can adopt below solution in my answer.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Thanks. I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will take advantage of *import caching*:

```
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory({
  /* pass a configuration object here if needed */
})


// index.js (example)
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>
), holder)


// interceptor.js
import axios from 'axios';
import cookie from 'cookie-machine';
import history from '../history';

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, function(err) {
  if ( err.status === 401 ) {
    cookie.remove('my-token-key');
    history.push('/login');
  }

  return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

Comment: I used history library. It doesn't work for me. Only changed the browser url. Not redirect.

Comment: You have to export the instance of browserHistory, not browserHistory itself

Comment: I do the same thing in your answer. Instead of 'Router', I am using 'BrowserRouter' from react-router-dom. What do you mean by "export the instance of browserHistory, not browserHistory itself".

Comment: Take a look at my history.js file, if it is exported like this for both app and axios abstraction, they refer to the same history object

Comment: I use this method when I do no have redux, while using redux I simply dispatch an action that act on the same history object

Comment: I am using <HashRouter>. This solution is not working with <HashRouter>. How to make it work with HashRouter?

Comment: Is this still a valid appraoch?

Comment: @HemanthaDhanushka the same problem occurs with me

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by passing `useHistory()` from inside a `<Router>` to axios interceptors.

App.js:

```
// app.js

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <InjectAxiosInterceptors />

      <Route ... />
      <Route ... />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

InjectAxiosInterceptors.js:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
import { setupInterceptors } from "./plugins/http"

function InjectAxiosInterceptors () {
  const history = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('this effect is called once')
    setupInterceptors(history)
  }, [history])

  // not rendering anything
  return null
}
```

plugins/http.js:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://url'
})

/**
 * @param {import('history').History} history - from useHistory() hook
 */
export const setupInterceptors = history => {
  http.interceptors.response.use(res => {
    // success
    return res
  }, err => {
    const { status } = err.response
  
    if (status === 401) {
      // here we have access of the useHistory() from current Router
      history.push('/login')
    }
  
    return Promise.reject(err)
  })
}

export default http
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a history object to push new location. Check this question [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4). This should help.

Comment: I used history library. It doesn't work for me. Only changed the browser url. No redirection happen.