# Change the route but dont navigate in React + React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using a multiple step form, this one: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/checkout/

It works perfectly. But i need to update the url when I change the step.

My first thought was to use a redirect, but it seems very complicated.

```
  if (newCheckout) return <Redirect to={`checkout/${newCheckout}`} />;
```

Is there any way to achieve that without redirecting?.

I dont want to lose the data from my component. **Just update the route.**. .

Comment: Use history.pushState() .

Comment: Thanks @oct51, but that is from mozila? or I can do it with react-router-dom. Checking my props, I have history.push(path, state), should I use this?

Comment: Sorry I am on the phone. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4

Comment: Are you using react-router? If so, what version?

Comment: use Link rather Redirect

Comment: last version @Hinrich