# Dont render until data has loaded - react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react-router for navigation. I wat the transition between routes to be like that of youtube and facebook. I have API calls in each component on mount. I am trying to prevent the next url (component) from loading until it has fetched the data (like youtube). Instead what I want is that the current component remain visible with a top progress bar until the next url( component) has finished getting its data. How can I get this done in react? Thank you

Comment: This is a little vague. Do you already have code written? Do you have your progress bar already? Are you asking how to render it or how to style it? Sharing code with a specific problem is a better way to get your question answered.

Comment: I dont ecause I am a little lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need your fetch to take place in a parent component. Then, you can render whichever component you want based on the state of fetch. If fetching is done, render the NewComponent. If still fetching, render the CurrentComponent.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const CurrentComponent = () => <div>I am current</div>;
const NewComponent = () => <div>I am new</div>;

const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // this simulates your fetch
  setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 2000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Component:</h2>
      {loading ? <CurrentComponent /> : <NewComponent />}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

#### Or with React-Router:

Do your fetch and when your fetch completes use `history.push` to go to your new route. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/9211387).

Comment: hmmm....Okay I am trying my best to understand that

Comment: I added a better example

Comment: Thank you very much, ut I am using react router. Is there anyway this can be integrated with react router

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. See the link to the post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/9211387

Comment: great name you've got there: almost as good as mine

Comment: haha :'-D. Over here it's a pretty common name.