# when button is clicked, It should redirect to other page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I clicked on Submit button, It should redirect me to another page, Where my other all pages should display there..
This is the submit page, Where I written one function to redirect to Home page.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home';

class App extends Component {

  constuctor() {

  }

  routeChange=()=> {
    this.props.history.push("/Home");
  }

  render () {
  return (
   <div>
       <center>
          <div>
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address : </label>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter email"/>
        </div>

        <div>
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password : </label>
        <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <button  type="submit"  onClick={this.routeChange} >Submit</button>
        </center>

   </div>
  )
}
}

export default App;
```

This is my Home page,Where I have written code for routing for all other pages

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Posts from './posts';
import Profile from './profile';


 class Home extends Component {

    render() {
    return (
      <div>



<center>
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
  <header>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
 <Link to="/Posts">Posts</Link> 
  <Link to="/Profile">Profile</Link>

  </header>
<Route exact path ="/" component={Home}></Route>
<Route path ="/Posts" component={Posts}></Route>
<Route path ="/Profile" component={Profile}></Route>
</div>
</BrowserRouter>
</center>

</div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I clicked on Submit button , It should take me to other Page.

Comment: can you add your root component in your question.

Comment: Index.js file : ReactDOM.render(
<App />
document.getElementById('root'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When want to navigate to `/Home`,

```
this.props.history.push("/Home");
```

But you don't have any `Route` to handle this navigation.

You can do this,

```
this.props.history.push("/");   //This will navigate to your `Home` component
```

Also you need to wrap your component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC.

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest `<Route>'s` match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';



class App extends Component {
   ...
}

export default withRouter(App)
```

---

Another way is using [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect). When using `Redirect`, you don't need `withRouter` HOC.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';



class App extends Component {

  routeChange=()=> {
    return <Redirect to="/Home" />
  }

  ...
}

export default App
```

---

**Update**

Your `App` component is outside of your `Router`, so in this case you can not use `Redirect` or `withRouter` for navigation.

To use proper navigation, your `App` component should be inside of `Router`.

Check the demo below, I have restructure your code a bit to fit it into your requirement.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-stuvqf)

Comment: I have tried with "withRouter", But I am facing this error : Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Comment: Oh yes. App is your standalone component and not present in Route's. In this case you can make use of `Redirect`.

Comment: with using Redirect also unable to redirect to another page 
routeChange=()=> {
    console.log("button clicked");
    return <Redirect to="/Home" />
   
  }

Comment: @sundeep, check the updated answer and Demo link. In the Demo, I have modified your code so that everything should fall under the Router and navigation should work properly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have `/Home` path. So, change this:

```
this.props.history.push("/Home");
```

with this:

```
this.props.history.push("/");
```

Comment: Tried , But Its not redirected to another page

Comment: It is saying :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: @sundeep import `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`, and then wrap your component with `withRouter`. Like this: `export default withRouter(App)`.

Comment: Ya I have done that, But facing this Issue :  ×
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Home` component, and a `/` route

And you are trying to render the `/Home` route that doesn't exist

You have 2 options:

1) Redirect the user to `/` that will render the `Home` component by using

`routeChange=()=> {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }`

2) Add a route to `/Home` that will also render the `Home` Component
 `<Route path ="/Home" component={Home}></Route>`

Comment: With 1st Approach I am Facing this problem ,TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: You need to pass the history to the Router when declaring it and also the HOC . Please check https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components

And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4

Answer (score 0):

first things is that you have to wrapped first component that i dont know which comp is, wrappe by `BrowserRouter` and in inner comp if wrapped your routes by `Switch`.

```
render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    document.getElementById('App')
);
```

and in app js you can use this:

```
this.props.history.push("/");
```

and in the inner component that related route define in home.js, you can use below هnstructions.
Base on 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

in App.js at forst import withRouter

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class App extends React.Component {
handleClick = () => {
   this.props.history.push("/");
}
render () {
  return (
   <div onClick={this.handleClick}></div>
  )
}
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

you can use it for click on button instead of div.

Comment: I have tried with "withRouter", But I am facing this error : Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Comment: i know what you say, i edit my answer base your need.

Comment: Ok My first Componet is App component only and in  Index.js File I have given Like this : ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'))..... So I need to wrap my Index.js file with Browser router??

Comment: wrapped your App file in index.js by BrowserRoute

Comment: Still Unable to redirect to another page ..I wrap my App file with Browser router and Inner componet with Switch : <Switch>
<div>
  <header>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
 <Link to="/Posts">Posts</Link> 
  <Link to="/Profile">Profile</Link>

  </header>
<Route exact path ="/" component={Home}></Route>
<Route path ="/Posts" component={Posts}></Route>
<Route path ="/Profile" component={Profile}></Route>
</div>
</Switch>