# Confusion with props passed into render in React R

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and encountered the below code which uses React Router:

```
<Router>
  <NavLink to="/homepage">Homepage</NavLink>
  <Route path="/homepage" render={props => 
  (<Homepage {...props} pieceOfState={this.state.pieceOfState}/>)
}/>
</Router>
```

The question is Does props passed into render "render={**props** =>..."  represent router props like with objects match, location and history?

Comment: You don't need to pass it on that way if you use for example `withRouter` where you are defining your component in this case `Homepage` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...props`  does stand for match, location and history. This syntax is used when you have extra props to pass. Like in this case, `this.state.pieceOfState`

From the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func):

> The render prop function has access to all the same route props
>   (match, location and history) as the component render prop.

You can also individually pass the required props by:

```
<Route path="/homepage" render={({ match }) => 
  (<Homepage match={match} pieceOfState={this.state.pieceOfState}/>)
```

Comment: so you mean here "render={props => we are passing router props so that we can access match, history and location inside render method of a route. Is that right?

Comment: yes, that's right. It's automatically passed for you in case the [`component`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component) prop in `Route`

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to decorate your app with router stuff one could be for in main `app.js` to have something like

```
<Router
  history={history}
>
 <App />
</Router>
```

this way you do not need to pass exact props to component itself.

For more details you can check this one [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<Route path="/" render={() => <Homepage data={passPropsHere} />} />
```

is side Homepage you can get your props like :

```
console.log('your props is here', this.props.data);
```