# How can I reroute to a new page if a POST operation is successful?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

After I fill a form in react, and I posted to the working API, I want it to reroute back to /dashboard.
I will paste the code that is working

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ERRORS } from './types';


const createProject = (project, history) => async dispatch => {
  await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/project', project)


    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: error.response.data
      });
    });
};


export default createProject;
```

Answer (score 1):

use History instead of window.location

```
// src/actions/userActionCreators.js

// ...
import history from '../history';
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ERRORS } from './types';

const createProject = (project, history) => async dispatch => {
  await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/project', project)

    history.push('/');

    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: error.response.data
      });
    });
};

export default createProject;
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4