# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when using useHistory() hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-hooks

i have an onClick event on a button that pushes requests to a server and should go back to the homepage afetr submitting , i tried to use the Reactjs useHistory hooks on that component ,however i keep getting the error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`.

I need help to get around it

Comment: You have an argument or something set to an Object that should be a function. Note if you have `function test(){}` you would just pass `test` without a parameters, because it would be executed first otherwise.

Comment: can you start by sharing your code ?

Answer (score 7):

Are you using [react-router: 5.1.0](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0)? `useHistory` and other hooks didn't become available until then. I was getting the same error as OP using the simplest implementation and then realized I was only on `react-router: 5.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are only using the react library but useHistory is part of react-router library.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/hooks.md

If adding the react-router not fix the issue. Please add some code so we can help.

Comment: i am using react-router-dom

Comment: i was Importing useHistory from 'react' instead of 'react-router-dom'

Answer (score 2):

I was getting error -

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Solution -
Looks like `usehistory` was deprecated for react-router-dom v6 and up. Instead try using `useNavigate`

Example -

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/home')
```

Docs -
You can view the official docs [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.0.0-beta.0/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#use-navigate-instead-of-history) from react-router

Answer (score 0):

You can see this error

```
TypeError: Object(…) is not a function
```

when using useHistory() hooks in React class. You are not supposed to do it. Instead you are better to use the `withRouter` high-order component for class or `context` API, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/4791116).The basic example is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  ...

  handleEvents = (e) => this.props.history.push('another-route')

  render(){
    return <div onClick={e => handleEvents(e)}>Hello World!</div>
  }
}

const MyClassWithRouter = withRouter(MyClass)
export MyClassWithRouter
```

Comment: That's not necessarily the case and OP doesn't mention anything about whether he uses classes or hooks. So I find it somewhat bold to assume that he necessarily uses React classes in an answer :P (rather than discussing it in comments) In my case the issue was that I didnt have updated react-router and react-router-dom to >5.0.