# redirect to the same component re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm using the same `Form` component for editing a post and adding a new one in my application. The componentDidMount of `Form` looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.match ? this.props.dispa({
        type: 'ON_LOAD_ACTION',
        payload: this.props.fetch.data.find(x => x.id == this.props.match.params.id)
    }) : this.props.dispa({
        type: 'ON_RESET',
        payload: ''
    });
}
```

It checks if there's an `id` on the URL, e.g. `localhost:3000/edit/id`

I'm trying to update a post. I extract the data of the post and I can fill the form with it. If there's no `id` on the URL I just render the form empty. The second dispatch is for resetting the state to its initial state.

I'm using `react-router`/`redux` and my problem is when I'm on the edit form and click on create form. It doesn't re-render and I got the value of the post I was in. I think that it's because i'm redirecting to the same form.

```js
     <Route exact path="/create" >
       <FromProduct />
       </Route>
     <Route exact path="/edit/:id" component={FromProduct}></Route>
```

But if I click on `submit` button to update the post or I go to the `/home` first, the component re-renders perfectly.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4

Comment: The problem is probably that `componentDidMount` is not called again because the component is already mounted, try to add this check in the `componentDidUpdate` method as well.

Comment: hey, i 'already try same result

Comment: @FaroukYD it's always nice to provide a sandbox (codesandbox, for instance) example for complex scenarios like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to see the problem:

1. React-router doesn't unmounts `FromProduct` component on each Route change. This is causing the behavior you described, you're seeing the same component always. You could try to force a re-render with an inline function.
2. Since your `componentDidMount` is not being called again, you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` on the `FromProduct` component. This way, for each Route change, it'll be executed even if it was mounted, because it'll now receive new props.

**Solution #1 is not really recommended.** The solution #2 would be doing something like this:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  // very similar logic for componentDidMount
  // but use newProps instead of this.props
}
```

If you still want to try Solution #1, please check React router's documentation about inline rendering [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component).