# React Router ^6.0.0-beta.0 history prop removal - navigating outside of react context

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

According to the latest v6.0.0-alpha.5 release of react router, the history prop has been removed: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v6.0.0-alpha.5

> Removed the  prop and moved responsibility for setting
> up/tearing down the listener (history.listen) into the wrapper
> components (, , etc.).  is now a
> controlled component that just sets up context for the rest of the
> app.

Navigating within the react context is simple with the useNavigate hook.

but now in the current V6 how the removal of history prop from BrowserRouter effect the navigation outside of the router context?
For example, if I have a Service class like that:

```
    class Service {
    
    constructor() {
        let service = axios.create({
            baseURL: BASE_URL,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            timeout: 60000,
            withCredentials: true
        });
        
        this.service = service;
    }

    handleError(path, err) {
        if (axios.isCancel(err)) { // Catch axios request cancelation
            console.log('caught cancel', err.message)
        } 
        else if ( err.response && err.response.status === 401) { // Unauthorized
            console.log('user unautorized');

            window.location.href = '/auth/login'
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Had Issues getting to the backend, endpoint: ${path}, with data: ${null}`);
            console.dir(err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
    
    async get(path, params, loaderTrackerArea) {
        try {
            const response = await trackPromise(this.service.request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: path,
                params
            }), loaderTrackerArea);

            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            this.handleError(path, err);
        }
    }
}
export default new Service();
```

Now, what I want to get is in the handleError function redirect to login page, currently I used pure javascript solution, what is the best way to achieve that with the current version of react-router-dom?

Thanks all!!!

Comment: If it is a production app, you should not be using an `alpha` version of any library. Alpha versions are a version of the library that is made available for testing. Nevertheless, react hooks are only to be used in React component. This is not a react component. Where are you using this in your React component?

Comment: I'm using v6.0.0-beta.0, now i know inside my component I can use useNavigate if the server response 401(Unauthorized), but if I have a lot places that I will be getting this response I want in one place redirect to login page and not in every component checking if the response is 401 redirect to login

Comment: Again, don't use the alpha or beta version of a library if it's a production app. It is not recommended. Hooks cannot be used out of React component. So, you have to either pass history to your method or pass a callback on success.

Comment: OK got you, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875097/112377

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (since the issue is still in the final release). While there isn't an existing interface to pass in a custom history object, it is actually quite easy to write custom wrapper around the `Router` component, based on the `BrowserRouter` implementation.

See https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8241#discussioncomment-1677474 for code.

**Edit:**
As of react-router-dom v6.1.0 HistoryRouter is part of its implementation so you can just directly do:

```js
import {HistoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<HistoryRouter history={history} />
```