# history.push() and Custom URL parameters using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create an app where users can join groups, and one of the pages I have is a group dashboard. For this, I created a route with a URL parameter of id.

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <LoggedRoute exact path = "/" component = {Home}/>
        <Route exact path = "/login" component = {Login}/>
        <Route exact path = "/groups/:id" component = {GroupDash}/>
    </div>
</Router>
```

When a user creates a group, it persists it in my database, and gets the docID to use as the url parameter.

I then use `history.push("/groups/".concat(docID))` to attempt to re-direct my user to the new page. However, **this doesn't work** and instead takes me to `.../groups/` vs `.../groups/docID`.

I initially thought that this was because the string, `docID` wasn't being created properly, but after logging the string to the console, it is correct.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4) helps?

Comment: @haensl not really, since Im able to successfuly use history.push for other links. I'm just having trouble passing in URL parameters using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't use [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch), I am not sure why. Here is how to use [`URL Parameters`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) correctly in react-router:

**Routes:**

```
<Router>
  <Switch> {/* Use Switch */}
    <LoggedRoute exact path = "/" component = {Home}/>
    <Route exact path = "/login" component = {Login}/>
    <Route exact path = "/groups" component = {Groups}/> {/* This should be exact */}
    <Route exact path = "/groups/:id" component = {GroupDash}/> {/* This exact can be optional for this use case */}
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

And you can do `history.push` to go to that route:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    history.push(`/groups`)
  }}
>
  Groups
</button>
<button
  onClick={() => {
    history.push(`/groups/${1234}`)
  }}
>
  Groups dashboard
</button>
```

And to get the `id` in your component, you can use [`useParams`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook or use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC (use `props.match.params?.id` for the HOC):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function GroupDash() {
  let { id } = useParams()

  return <>Group Dash: {id}</>
}
```