# how to pass data between routes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, routes, router

I have a signup page signup.js after successful sign in I need to take those data to another route view sign in details  page if I render sign in details then I am viewing it in the same page how to take it to another route ??If I do through window.name after refresh I couldn't view the data[my page layout]

```
1st page
class Validation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     
    this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
   
   }
validate(detail,number) {
//i need to take this number to view page 
    });
     
      
  
 
   }
  render() {
    
     return (
      <div>
        
        <SignupForm onAddDetail={this.validate} />
             
        
      </div>);
  }
}
  
export default Validation;
2nd page


class DetailsComponent extends Component {
  
  render() {
       let DetailNodes = this.props.details.map(detail => 
       (
        <Register key={detail.id}  
          emailId={detail.emailId} password={detail.password}
           firstName={detail.firstName} lastName={detail.lastName}
            location={detail.location} mobileNumber={detail.mobileNumber}>
          
           
        </Register>
        
      )
       
      );
         
      return (
       
        <div> <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
               
              {DetailNodes[number-1]}//I need that number from 1st page and carried here
                            
               <br/>
               
    </div>);

}
  
}

route.js    
my route page
<Route path="/signup" component={Validation}/>
           
 <Route path="/view"  component={DetailsComponent} />
```

Comment: Use `history.push` to pass location data as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237212/2873538).

Comment: this is working if  I  move from signup page to view page .If I move directly to view route the value becomes undefined .I have signup values in signup page without redirecting if I directly clicks that view route also I need to have those values is there anyway??

Comment: Store the data in a central store like Redux and any component can read from there.

Comment: I am very new to react any example or website link will be useful. please consider my request

Comment: Here is how to do it: 1. User enters email/password 2. Login is successful and API returns user details (and, maybe auth tokens) 3. Store user details (and, maybe auth tokens) in LocalStorage 4. *Read* from localstorage wherever (any component) you need to show user details.

Comment: Are you using Redux? Do you need resources on "How to add Redux to your app?"

Comment: Already I used redux to store my registration details but for local storage I have no idea. Is it possible to store id (integer value ) and retrieve it ??can I get any source for local storage and retrieving it

Comment: If you have stored **user details in Redux**, it will be lost when you reload (F5 button) the page. Is this (losing user details in Redux at refresh) your problem?

Comment: See the last *Edit* part in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550417/2873538 to fix above (losing user details in Redux at refresh) issue.

Comment: Thanku so much using local storage iam able to get it even after refresh. I didn't do anything to fix it even though it's working after refresh

Answer (score 1):

As option you can do it like this:

add field to state

```
success: true | false
```

and if signup is successfull

```
setState({success: true})
```

and in signup component add ternary

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

!success ? <SignUp /> : <Redirect to={{
                                    pathname: '/view',
                                    state: {data: signUpCredentials}
                                }}
                                />
```

and in View component you can access it in

```
{props.location.state}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`useHistory()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook of React router.

For eg:

```
const history = useHistory();

...

history.push('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props from Route render. You can do this in multiple ways. If your data is available at router level. Like below. Or setup up a Store for shared data

```
const myProps = {x,y,z}

<Route path="/signup" render={()=> <Validation myNewProp='someprop' />} />             
<Route path="/view"  render={()=> <DetailsComponent {...myProps} />} />
```