# Redirect page upon login using react-router-v5 and redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm using react-router-dom v5.2.

Upon login, I want my page to redirect to `/home` from `/`. The login form is at `/`.

When I try to perform authentication without any async function (ie. comparing username and password to hardcoded values in react), everything works perfectly.

But when I do perform authentication using express and mongo, the redirection upon login stops working. If I login again, then the redirection happens. Protected routes still work (redirect to login page if the user is not logged in).

Here's a small demo of the problem where I use do auth with express + mongo ie. async redux. This is not working as intended. https://youtu.be/Zxm5GOYymZQ

Here's the link of the app where I use hardcoded username and password (both "test") to do auth. No async here. This works as intended. Username and password are both "test". https://poke-zoo.herokuapp.com/

---

Here's `App.js`:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authState = useSelector(selectorAuth)
  // const location = useLocation()
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (authState.isUserLoggedIn) {
          return <Component {...props} />
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location,
                },
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div tw="flex flex-col bg-green-100 min-h-screen">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/explore" component={Explore} />
          <Route path="*" component={() => "404 Not found."} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Here's `ModalLogin.js`.

```
const ModalLogin = props => {
  const { loginModalBool, setLoginModalBool } = props
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const history = useHistory()

  const attemptLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(tryLogin(username, password))
    history.push("/home")
  }

  return (
    <div tw="flex flex-col text-center h-full w-64 bg-gray-200 text-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-lg p-2 md:p-4 lg:p-6">
      <div tw="flex flex-row justify-between">
        <p tw="text-lg">Login</p>
        <button tw="text-sm" onClick={() => setLoginModalBool(!loginModalBool)}>
          close
        </button>
      </div>
      <div tw="flex flex-col justify-around my-1">
        <form onSubmit={attemptLogin} tw="">
          <input
            tw="my-1"
            value={username}
            onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="username"
          />
          <input
            tw="my-1"
            value={password}
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            type="password"
            placeholder="password"
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            tw="my-1 p-1 rounded bg-gray-800 text-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-900"
          >
            log in
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's the `authSlice.js`.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import axios from "axios"

const initialState = {
  isUserLoggedIn: false,
  username: "",
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      const user = action.payload

      if (!user) return alert("Login failed. Incorrect username or password.")

      state.username = user.username
      state.isUserLoggedIn = true
    },
    logout: (state, action) => {
      // window.localStorage.removeItem("loggedInUser")
      state.username = ""
      state.isUserLoggedIn = false
    },
    signup: (state, action) => {
      const user = action.payload
      state.username = user.data.username
      state.isUserLoggedIn = true
    },
  },
})

export const tryLogin = (username, password) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/auth/login", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })

      const user = {
        token: response.headers["auth-token"],
        username: response.data.username,
      }

      // window.localStorage.setItem("token", response.headers["auth-token"])

      dispatch(login(user))
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Incorrect Username/Password.")
    }
  }
}

export const selectorAuth = state => state.auth
export const { login, logout } = authSlice.actions
export default authSlice.reducer
```

---

Am I using react-router with redux-toolkit incorrectly?

Here's the [Github repo](https://github.com/theairbend3r/poke-zoo)

Comment: Horeku link works on me, disable your extentions

Comment: Yes, the heroku links works. Because it does not contain the async auth using express and mongo. But when use express and mongo for it (as shown in the video), the redirect stops working.

Comment: My bad, i was reading fast:D I've cloned and fixed your code. You can try and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code does not define redirection logic after login. You can do it in two way.

1st : You can define another redirection wrapper for authentication if you want your routes to redirect in case of authentication.

```js
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authState = useSelector(selectorAuth)
  const location = useLocation()
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (!authState.isUserLoggedIn) {
          return <Component {...props} />
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/home",
                state: {
                  from: location,
                },
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div tw="flex flex-col bg-green-100 min-h-screen">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          // It is for login users to redirect to home page
          <AuthRoute exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/explore" component={Explore} />
          <Route path="*" component={() => "404 Not found."} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

2nd : Another approach can be imperatively handling with history.push() or history.replace() :

```js
const Layout = () => {
  const authState = useSelector(selectorAuth);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    // if isUserLoggedIn turned to true redirect to /home
    if (authState.isUserLoggedIn) { 
      history.push("/home");
    }
  }, [authState.isUserLoggedIn]); // triggers when isUserLoggedIn changes

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/explore" component={Explore} />
      <Route path="*" component={() => "404 Not found."} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div tw="flex flex-col bg-green-100 min-h-screen">
        <Navbar />
        <Layout />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**Why didn't your code work?** Take a look at the code below :

```
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/explore" component={Explore} />
      <Route path="*" component={() => "404 Not found."} />
```

**What it does?**
It checks your browser path and check if it matches with given Route rule from top to down. If Route path matches then it renders the component if not it continues through down visiting each one of Route until it matches your 404.

So back to your case; when you login, you were not leaving "/" path. Because there is no logic implemented to leave the "/" path. So it again match with landing page even though it is authenticated. It matches with route path (Landing page) and stays there. It does not continue and try your logic on ProtectedRoute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works now! :D 
But I didn't really understand why it works now what I was doing wrong earlier? Could you please explain it a bit more? React-router is really confusing to me (not a lot of places that explain what is actually going on). 

Also, can you explain (with code) the 2nd approach? I was following the along the code from the link you mentioned before I got stuck.

Comment: I am using 2rd approch in useEffect use history.push("/login")  but its give error push undefind

Comment: @PriyankaSankhala You should ensure that you have access to the history object. You can verify it by `console.log(history)` just after its definition.

Answer (score 2):

The current accepted answer fixes your issues, but does not properly identify the reason that you were having trouble.  So I want to explain it for you (and anyone else reading this).

#### Problem: Redirecting Too Soon

```
const attemptLogin = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  dispatch(tryLogin(username, password))
  history.push("/home")
}
```

This code dispatches the `tryLogin` and the **immediately** calls `history.push("/home")`.  It does not wait for the dispatched action to complete and update the store.

When you call `history.push("/home")` your app loads the `ProtectedRoute` for component `Home`.  Inside the `ProtectedRoute` you use a selector to examine the value of `authState.isUserLoggedIn`.  If it is `false`, then you redirect to `"/"`.

So if you redirect to `"/home"` before the value of `authState.isUserLoggedIn` has been updated then you will end up getting redirected back to `"/"` instead of being able to view the `Home` component.

That's why you are having these issues with asynchronous authentication:

> When I try to perform authentication without any async function (ie. comparing username and password to hardcoded values in react), everything works perfectly.
>
> But when I do perform authentication using express and mongo, the redirection upon login stops working.

#### Solution: Wait Before Redirecting

You need to wait for the `authState` to update **before** redirecting to a protected route.

There's a lot of ways to do this, but in general we want to use selectors to listen for changes being posted to the redux state.  Here's one approach which uses the `ModalLogin` to conditionally render a `Redirect` component.  I would also recommend including some sort of selector for login errors in case the dispatch finishes resolving but the login was unsuccessful.  You would want to show an error message to the user in the modal.

```
const ModalLogin = props => {
  const { loginModalBool, setLoginModalBool } = props
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const history = useHistory()
  
  // Look at the authState from redux.  This value will automatically update.
  const authState = useSelector(selectorAuth)

  const attemptLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(tryLogin(username, password))
    // don't redirect here anymore
  }

  // Once logged in, render the redirection
  if ( authState.isUserLoggedIn ) {
     return (
       <Redirect to="/home" />
     );
  }
  
  // Otherwise, render the modal
  return (
    /* your current code */
  )
}
```

Answer (score -4):

to be honest, what i do is use plain old javascript to change the location when the user is logged in

```
window.location = "/redirect"
```

Comment: Where would I put in the above files? ModalLogin.js? Any react-router way to do it?

Comment: thanks, sometimes the easiest way is the best way...