# How can you redirect user to another page.js on form submission in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, forms, redirect

i have a log in form in react js and i cant redirect user to another page.js on submit

```
render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.submitForm.bind(this)}>
                <div>
                    <label>username</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}/>
                </div>
                <button type='submit'>Login</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

submitForm (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.history.push('/Cards.js');
      }
```

it wont redirect any ideas?

Comment: Assuming usage of `react-router-dom`... is the component properly rendered within a `Route` component or otherwise decorated with the `withRouter` HOC? Can you update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? Actually, your push is incorrect, you need to push to a defined route in your `Router`. It won't understand what "/Cards.js" is really.

Comment: Here's a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154408/redirect-page-upon-login-using-react-router-v5-and-redux-toolkit

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for the help i was missing the <Route exact path='/cards component = {Cards}> 
i have a project to do and im new to reactjs thanks for the help..